# Шаблонные комментарии в очереди проверок

Tags: предложение, очередь-проверок, шаблонные-комментарии

Учитывая [количество вопросов и ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review), для которых необходима проверка (часто по делу) сильно не хватает шаблонных комментариев как на Хэшкоде:

- Про фриланс
- Про форматирование кода
- Про грамматику и орфографию
- Про малоинформативные ответы-ссылки

К сожалению Хэшкод не доступен, чтобы посмотреть какие там были комментарии...

Comment: Задача решается через расширение для браузера или пользовательский скрипт: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1225/181472

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Список шаблонных комментариев, которые использовались на ХэшКоде.

1. `@{{ post.author }}`, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.
2. `@{{ post.author }}`, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.
3. `@{{ question.author }}`, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).
4. `@{{ post.author }}`, используйте, пожалуйста, кириллицу.
5. `@{{ post.author }}`, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.
6. `@{{ post.author }}`, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.
7. `@{{ post.author }}`, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.
8. `@{{ post.author }}`, Оформляйте ответы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.
9. `@{{ post.author }}`, Оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.
10. `@{{ post.author }}`, Stack Overflow на русском это не фриланс биржа. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос, уточните, что сделали сами, что не получилось.
11. `@{{ post.author }}`, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Comment: А менюшку такую же реально будет добавить?

Comment: Что-то подсказывает мне, что нет. Думаю, как минимум первое время мы будем работать только с имеющимися инструментами. Я исследую вопрос, потому что тоже нахожу такой функционал очень полезным.

Comment: Видимо SO пользуется более серьезными инструментами - закрытие, заморозка, правка самих ответов/вопросов вплоть до изменения чуть ли ни всего текста. На ХК комментарии часто не приводили к положительному результату, в особенности в вопросах новичков. Вполне возможно, шаблонные комментарии в будущем могут быть и не нужны. Поживем, увидим. Вопрос пусть повисит, может что-то поменяется к лучшему.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Попытался проанализировать представленные вами комментарии и их аналоги на СО в своём ответе. Как "ромба", прошу проверить. :)

Answer (score 4):

Я бы уточнил сценарии использования "шаблонных комментариев". Политика на СО заметно отличается от политики на ХК.

> @{{ post.author }}, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Если дана задачка без описания проблемы, то это причина для закрытия "слишком широкий вопрос": непонятно, что именно объяснять, а объяснять всё — слишком долго.

Некоторые используют для закрытия "оффтопичную" причину SSCCE.

> @{{ post.author }}, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Эта подсказка должна выползать при редактировании. Если юзер проигнорировал тогда, то вряд ли отреагирует на комментарий.

Также абсолютно любой пользователь может отредактировать пост самостоятельно. Если репы мало, то правка попадёт в очередь.

> @{{ question.author }}, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Эта подсказка тоже самостоятельно выползает, вроде. Модераторы комментарии с подобными напоминаниями не любят и выпиливают, как только увидят.

> @{{ post.author }}, используйте, пожалуйста, кириллицу.

До сих пор на СО было неактуально, поэтому поведение неясно.

> @{{ post.author }}, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

"Оффтопичная" причина закрытия вопроса со ссылкой на SSCCE (или СОшный аналог).

> @{{ post.author }}, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Выбрать причину для закрытия вопроса по вкусу. "Непонятно, в чём вопрос", например.

> @{{ post.author }}, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Так как СО пользуются в том числе те, кто в английском не бум-бум, то на грамматику указывать не принято. Можно отредактировать самостоятельно. Вряд ли автор сможет написать лучше — если бы мог, написал бы.

> @{{ post.author }}, Оформляйте ответы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.
>      @{{ post.author }}, Оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Слишком широкий и бесполезный комментарий. Я бы не рекомендовал писать что-то подобное, потому что автору не указывается чёткая причина и пути исправления.

> @{{ post.author }}, Stack Overflow на русском это не фриланс биржа. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос, уточните, что сделали сами, что не получилось.

Причину "we are not code monkeys" просят давно. :) Пока можно закрывать как "слишком широкий вопрос", как и в случае со школьными задачками. Впрочем, эти самые code monkeys, жаждущие работать за репу, часто находятся...

> @{{ post.author }}, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Флаг "пост только со ссылкой". Что с ними происходит — тайна, покрытая мраком. Похоже, обычно ничего, особенно если это единственный ответ.

Comment: `> Если дана задачка без описания проблемы, то это причина для закрытия "слишком широкий вопрос": непонятно, что именно объяснять, а объяснять всё — слишком долго.`

Но зачем закрывать, если можно помочь пользователю улучшить вопрос.?

Comment: `> Эта подсказка должна выползать при редактировании. Если юзер проигнорировал тогда, то вряд ли отреагирует на комментарий.`

Как "ромб" на ХэшКоде не соглашусь. Новички вполне себе приучаются оформлять вопросы после напоминаний.

Comment: @Nofate Закрытие — это стадия улучшения, а не финальное состояние. Когда закрытый вопрос будет отредактирован, он автоматически попадёт в очередь на открытие. Более того, пометка на недавно закрытых вопросах — "on hold", а не "closed".

Comment: @Nofate На ХК при редактировании столько же подсказок выползает, как и на СО?

Comment: ок. Просто на ХэшКоде закрытые вопросы не часто открывались обратно. Чаще удалялись. Вообще, раз политика и workflow значительно изменились, хорошо бы увидеть от администрации своего рода Migration Guide на эту тему.

Comment: @Nofate На СО статистика по открытию закрытых вопросов тоже не блещет, мягко говоря. Но если автор адекватный, и вопрос осмысленный, то открытие особых проблем не вызывает.

Answer (score 2):

Как показывает опыт SO, "шаблонные комментарии" являются злом.

Хороший комментарий говорит в чём проблема с данным специфичным вопросом и указывает на конкретные пути её решения.

Шаблонный комментарий как правило вызывает негативную реакцию у людей. Плюс подобным инструментом очень легко злоупотребить: вместо вдумчивого комментария с участием сознания, люди на автомате нажимают на кнопку (обычно согласно некоторому упрощённому правилу). Кроме *исключительных* случаев, (например, таких как причины для закрытия,  которые также держат под контролем и постепенно улучшают, убирая те причины, которые особенно часто не по делу используются), всегда лучше если человек использует голову, а не бюрократические правила при общении с другим человеком.

Если нет сил оставить комментарий, специфичный для вопроса, то лучше предоставить эту возможность другим.

Если считать шаблонные комментарии допустимым злом, то существует [специальный скрипт](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) для них: [May we have some “canned comments”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283218/4279)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на скрипт, добавил для себя некоторые шаблоны.
Шаблонные комментарии - это не фиксированный список, а просто шаблон ответа, который можно и часто нужно распространить. Хорошо, когда один раз написал прекрасный комментарий, выполнил долг Проверяющего и через два клика попадается ну в точности такой же ответ или вопрос, к которому подошел бы такой же комментарий с изменением пары слов. Обидно бегать по истории и копировать его оттуда, вставлять, править и т.д.

Comment: Набросал [конфиг](https://gist.github.com/AlKach/ac95178fe5a0cd5d7206) для этого расширения (@jfs, спасибо за ссылку!), включающий в себя как шаблонные комментарии с Хэшкода, так и комменты с SO. Для того, чтобы править конфиг расширения, нужно в окне добавления шаблонного комментария перейти по ссылке `import/export`.

Comment: @fori1ton: линканул ваш гист с конфигом, надеюсь что вы не возражаете. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1226/181472

Comment: @fori1ton: кстати, обнаружил там юзерскрипт. Его можно использовать? Что он делает?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, этот юзерскрипт раскрашивает комментарии вот так: http://i.imgur.com/EiqZsvl.png. Комментарии каждого участника дискуссии раскрашиваются своим цветом, так легче следить за диалогом. Скрипт немного недоделан, если в дискуссии участвует много пользователей, цвета получаются слишком близкими и малоразличимыми - нужно придумать другой алгоритм, присваивающий цвета.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, насчёт моего конфига - конечно, не возражаю, для людей же делалось)

Comment: @fori1ton: спасибо, установил. Кажется, я тоже могу с вами поделиться кое-чем. Обратите внимание на отступы и кнопку `reply`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JYRjz.png

Comment: @fori1ton: а что если юзерпики участников прицеплять слева? Будет точно как в чате.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, мысль интересная, но поверхностный поиск показывает, что есть проблема с получением юзерпиков. Их можно получить только через API, но неавторизованные запросы к API быстро исчерпают квоту. Авторизация осуществляется через OAuth, поэтому мне будет нужен сервер, на который SO будет слать токен (https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication). Если бы хост диалога авторизации был stackoverflow.com, а не stackexchange.com, можно было бы извратиться, создав дочернее окно и отслеживая его URL (раздел Desktop Applications), но - не судьба, same origin policy не даёт так делать.

Comment: @fori1ton: повторно наткнулся и перечитал ваш ответ. Есть интересный скрипт, который через API обрабатывает ссылки в комментариях: [SE Comment Link Helper](http://stackapps.com/q/2378). Может быть, можно там подсмотреть решение. Я пока что в этом не разбираюсь. )

Answer (score 0):

Я читал такой комментарий, который мне нравился:

> Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/356878) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/356878).

Для копирования и вставки:

```
Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/356878) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/356878).
```