# Как должны выглядеть сообщения о закрытии вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

На мой взгляд, текущие сообщения о закрытии вопроса не содержат информации о том, как именно следует улучшить вопрос, чтобы получить ответ. В результате мы имеем две проблемы:

1. Самое обидное - закрытые вопросы не получают улучшающих правок от авторов.
2. Иногда вопросы закрываются напрасно, так как формулировка непонятна даже самим закрывающим.

> Мы, участники сообщества, голосующие за закрытие вопроса, не судьи, и не можем ими быть. Мы коллеги, желающие помочь. В большинстве случаев, смысл закрытия - подсказать автору, как улучить вопрос, чтобы получить более содержательный ответ.

Сейчас у нас есть пять основных причин закрытия вопросов:

1. является копией;
2. не по теме, потому что…;
3. непонятна суть вопроса;
4. всеобъемлющий;
5. по большей части зависит от мнения.

В случае, когда вопрос является дубликатом, все ясно.

Вопрос является нетематическим, если:

- автор обращается к сообществу с вопросом-опросником или вопросом поиска чего-либо (библиотеки, литературы и т. д.);
- в нем нет явного описания проблемы;
- он вызван опечаткой;
- не соответствует правилам, описанным в справке.

В принципе тут споров быть не должно, возможно, за исключением достаточности описания проблемы. Остальные причины закрытия, по моему мнению, можно использовать неправильно, если подходить к процессу закрытия вопросов поверхностно, так как эти причины достаточно субъективны.

Как мне кажется, необходимо:

1. либо дать четкие пояснения, что именно они подразумевают (причем пояснить необходимо как для закрывающего, так и для автора закрытого вопроса);
2. либо убрать их вообще, заменив на более конкретные.

Предлагаю начать с пояснения. Пожалуйста, подскажите:

- видите ли вы проблему с закрытием вопросов;
- если да, то как бы вы ее решили;
- какие пояснения к причинам закрытия необходимы по вашему мнению?

В общем, как на ваш взгляд можно улучшить существующую систему?

---

Связанные вопросы.

- [Кастомные причины для закрытия вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/92/).
- [Шаблонные комментарии в Проверке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13/).
- [Как и какие вопросы следует закрывать? В каких случаях?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Непонятна суть вопроса

*Чего мы хотим добиться от автора вопроса?* Чтобы автор уточнил вопрос:

- добавил пример кода, наглядно показывающий проблему;
- уточнил, в чем именно он видит проблему;
- пояснил, как эту проблему воспроизвести;
- что он хочет видеть в итоге.

*В каких случаях следует использовать эту причину?* Воспользуйтесь этой причиной закрытия, если:

- вопрос не содержит описания проблемы;
- вопрос не содержит описания желаемого результата;
- вопрос слишком короткий/объемный, и суть его неясна;
- вопрос слишком абстрактный.

*Текущая формулировка*.

> Пожалуйста, уточните, в чем состоит проблема, или укажите дополнительную информацию, чтобы стало ясно, в чем именно заключается вопрос. Сейчас практически невозможно понять, о чем именно вы спрашиваете. Чтобы разобраться, как правильно оформлять вопросы, посетите страницу "как задавать вопросы".

*Проблема.* Описание причины закрытия вопроса слишком длинное, в нем содержится две идеи: отсутствие детального описания проблемы и непонимание базовых подходов описания проблемы.

*Предлагаемое решение.* Упростить описание.

> Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

#### Всеобъемлющий

*Чего мы хотим добиться от автора вопроса?* Чтобы автор уточнил вопрос:

- явно ограничил проблемную область;
- четко описал проблему, желаемое решение и приближение, с которым хотелось бы получить ответ.

*В каких случаях следует использовать эту причину?* Воспользуйтесь этой причиной закрытия, если:

- вопрос подразумевает слишком объемный ответ;
- вопрос подразумевает слишком короткий ответ;
- вопрос подразумевает несколько правильных ответов.

*Текущая формулировка*.

> На этот вопрос можно дать слишком много ответов, либо же качественные ответы будут слишком длинными для данного формата. Пожалуйста, уточните подробности, чтобы сократить количество ответов или выделить проблему, ответ на которую будет занимать пару абзацев.

*Проблема.* Причина закрытия вопроса слишком всеобъемлющая. Как результат, при желании мы можем свести к имеющейся формулировке большое количество вопросов, и даже очень хороших.

*Предлагаемое решение.* Упросить описание.

> В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.

#### По большей части зависит от мнения

*Чего мы хотим добиться от автора вопроса?* Чтобы автор либо сформулировал вопрос так, чтобы он отвечал требованиям, либо удалил его.

*В каких случаях следует использовать эту причину?* Воспользуйтесь этой причиной закрытия, если:

- вопрос порождает бесконечные прения непримиримых оппонентов;
- вопрос порождает расширенные дискуссии как в комментариях, так и в ответах;
- вопрос подразумевает ответы, содержащие личное мнение или личное отношение к проблеме.

*Текущая формулировка*.

> Множество качественных вопросов сформировали определенное мнение, основанное на опыте специалистов. Ответы на этот вопрос, скорее всего, будут основаны только на мнениях, а не фактах, доказательствах или профессиональном опыте.

*Проблема.* Описание причины закрытия вопроса слишком размытое.

*Предлагаемое решение.* Уточнить описание.

> Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

#### Необходимые, на мой взгляд, дополнительные причины закрытия

*Низкое качество оформления.* Формулировка

> Оформление вопроса отталкивает участников, желающих поделиться знаниями. Для получения ответа, приведите ваш вопрос в порядок. Чтобы понять, как эффективнее это сделать, посетите страницу "как задавать вопросы".

*Вопрос-опросник.* Формулировка

> Вопросы-опросники запрещены в сообществе. Для получения ответа, перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ.

---

**Обновление**

Добавил вместо

> Вопросы с просьбами **предоставить рекомендации или найти книги, инструменты, библиотеки, материалы для обучения или любые другие внешние ресурсы** являются на Stack Overflow вопросами не по теме, так как приводят к спорам и спаму. Вместо этого опишите проблему и что вы сделали для её решения.

---

*Учебное задание.* Формулировка

> Согласно правилам сообщества, вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Для получения ответа приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Comment: Может, не "знатоков", а "экспертов" или как-нибудь еще? Вызывает ассоциации с ЧГК. =)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Спасибо за замечание. Исправил на более нейтральный вариант, хотя "знатоки" очень хорошее слово.

Comment: А вот это я что по-английски, что по-русски не понимаю: "Множество качественных вопросов сформировали определенное мнение, основанное на опыте специалистов.". Это значит что по этой теме уже есть множество качественных вопросов и нужно идти читать их?

Comment: То есть я понимаю, что значит "вопрос зависит от мнения" и в чем недостаток таких вопросов. Но эту фразу не могу понять. Для меня предлагаемая замена гораздо лучше.

Comment: _Низкое качество оформления_  - а насколько объективно низким оно должно быть? Если автор не смог в отступы в коде или в орфографию/пунктуацию, то можно отредактировать вопрос, исправив если не все недочёты, то хотя бы большинство, придав вопросу более-менее благоприятный вид.

Comment: _Учебное задание_, по-моему, вполне можно вынести из _Всеобъемлющий_, да. _Вопрос-опросник_ - а это не частный случай _По большей части зависит от мнения_?

Comment: @NickVolynkin В моем понимании это означает, что Java программисты считают язык Java позволяет решать задачу X более элегантно, а C++ программисты с ними не согласны. В любом случае, существующая формулировка до конца непонятна многим (включая меня), к сожалению.

Comment: @Regent _Низкое качество оформления_, как мне кажется, тут четких рамок нет. Я бы закрывал вопросы с такой формулировкой, например, если в них объемный код не выделен соответствующим образом или слишком много ошибок. То есть все вопросы, которые нельзя исправить достаточно быстро не прибегая к закрытию.

Comment: Мне кажется, вот что важно: можно ли вообще вопрос сделать отвечаемым или нет? Когда проблемы с форматированием, то обычно можно.

Comment: @Regent Основаная, на мой взгляд, проблема закрытия вопросов заключается в том, что такие вопросы очень редко открываются повторно. Как мне кажется, непонимание авторов того, чего от них хотят играет не последнюю роль. Чем более конкретна фраза закрытия вопроса, тем больше вероятность улучшающей правки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ответ на вопрос не самоцель. Конечная цель проекта - создание свободнораспостроняемой базы знаний прикладных решений. В этом случае все содержимое сайта необходимо оптимизировать для чтения.

Comment: Ещё: `Непонятна суть вопроса` несколько пересекается с `оффтопик` - `2 (где ссылка на mcve)`. В обоих случаях: код, проблема, воспроизведение, результат.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky _достаточно быстро_ - дело тоже относительное. Я немало времени трачу на редактирование вопросов. В некоторых с форматированием всё очень плохо, времени на правку уходит не минута и не две, но при этом вопрос сам по себе нормальный, на который кто-нибудь даст хороший ответ, особенно после правки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin вот в том и фокус: на вопрос ответить можно, но форматирование в нём просто кошмарное.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky "заставить" (закрытием вопроса или комментариями) автора отредактировать вопрос так, чтобы вопрос хорошо смотрелся - почти утопия :) Иногда "выбить" из автора _минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример_ - уже целая эпопея.

Comment: @Regent Если подходить к вопросу идеологически, то закрытие вопросов необходимо для того, чтобы 1) оградиться от ненужного шума, 2) подтолкнуть пользователей попробовать функционал. Да, вопрос может быть интересный, да, он скорее всего будет отвечен, но если пользователь не поймет, что надо публиковать структурированные вопросы, то сайт может превратиться в помойку.

Comment: @Regent Согласен с вами. Обычно, видя плохо оформленный вопрос от автора впервые, который требует серьезной правки, я вношу изменения и оставляю комментарий, указывающий на недочеты. Если в последствии я вижу безобразно оформленные вопросы от того же автора, я стараюсь их закрывать без правки. Мне кажется, тут следует придерживаться идеи "Если ребенку все время завязывать шнурки, он сам никогда не научиться этого делать".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я как раз за отсечение шума, и после большого SO действую иногда, возможно, жестче нужного. Вопросы, которые даже обширной правкой не спасти, стоит закрывать, я не спорю. Вопрос только ставить ли крест на тех, у кого вопрос нормальный, но правка слишком объёмная выходит. Далеко не всегда есть желание такое править, но и закрывать ли его? Вдруг кто-то потратит время на редактирование?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky весьма справедливо насчет шнурков :) Это, кстати, относится и к самому программированию: если весь код писать за автора, то он никогда не научится писать код сам. Ещё по поводу причин закрытия: весьма не хватает варианта в подменю "Не по теме"  _Не имеет никакого отношения к тематике SO_. Это про правильное распитие водки, и про Minecraft, и про сохранение изображений в Photoshop.

Answer (score 7):

А что если прямо переформулировать названия причин? Сейчас они звучат как диагнозы. "У вас всё плохо, вопрос - фигня".

Можно сделать из них некоторые призывы к действиям, которые приведут к улучшению вопроса.

Использую расшифровки, предложенные [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky), чтобы можно было оценить, как всё вместе смотрится.

> является копией;
>
> **этот вопрос уже был задан и имеет решение**
>
> **используйте решение из аналогичного вопроса**
>
> **your princess is in another castle**

---

> непонятна суть
>
> **необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса**
>
> **уточните подробности вопроса**
>
> *Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.*

---

> всеобъемлющий
>
> **необходимо конкретизировать вопрос**
>
> **конкретизируйте вопрос**
>
> **Ты скажи, ты скажи - чо те надо, чо те надо?**
>
> *В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.*

---

> по большей части зависит от мнения.
>
> **необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы решение было однозначным**
>
> **переформулируйте вопрос однозначным образом**
>
> *Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.*

Comment: Идея отличная! Только формулировки бы покороче придумать.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky добавил варианты с глаголами в повелительном наклонении

Comment: О, отлично! Слово «всеобъемлющий» не понимал, кажется, ни один автор вопроса.

Comment: @VladD еще можно вернуться к давно забытым "Аффтар выпей йаду"

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Ну, вполне можно добавить ещё язык локализации: ru-OLB.

Comment: @VladD я представляю себе причину закрытия на таком языке: "нидастатачна олбанскава в вапросе".

Comment: @VladD и точно так же сейчас не понимают "конкретизировать" .)

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Угу :) Проще надо быть, не для ботанов пишем :-D

Comment: @VladD вариант: "я не понял, че ты сказал? "

Comment: @NickVolynkin: «Чёта гониш не по пацански!»

Comment: @VladD для "too broad": "определись, чё ты хочешь?"

Comment: То есть конечно надо бы, хм, гуманизировать сообщения, приблизить к «живому языку». А то и правда _некоторым участникам_ (тм) не всегда понятно

Comment: @VladD приходите обсуждать. Тут наоборот предлагают вернуть старые формулировки. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1499/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Написал комментарий к вашему ответу.