# Список шаблонных комментариев

Tags: обсуждение, faq, шаблонные-комментарии

Многие могут помнить, что в старом движке [присутствовали шаблонные комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13/6), которыми сообщество активно пользовалось для подсказки авторам вопросов или ответов того, как  сделать их сообщения более информативными.

В текущем движке нет такой возможности, но мы видим, что многие пользователи, активно принимающие участие в управлении сообществом и содержимым сайта, имеют свой набор комментариев и используют их в тех или иных случаях.

Предлагаю составить список таких комментариев. Как мне кажется, список будет полезен многим. Спешу предложить формат одного общего ответа, который сообщество сможет дополнять и поддерживать. Обычно, комментарии преследуют цель запросить у автора улучшить ту или иную составляющую сообщения. Как результат, предлагаю группировать комментарии по целям, который мы хотим достичь его публикацией. Чтобы наши шаблонные комментарии было легко использовать всем, на мой взгляд, следует публиковать их так, чтобы они отображались в "сыром виде" (то есть с разметкой MarkDown).

Comment: А я знаю, как автоматизировать комментарии. Сейчас напишу. )

Comment: Да, я знаю несколько скриптов для этого. Пожалуйста, добавьте ваши рекомендации прямо в ответ (либо в вопрос).

Comment: Думаю, в отдельных ответах можно обсуждать некоторые комментарии, итоговые варианты по которым можно заносить в основной ответ

Comment: По поводу формата одного ответа: думаю, что стоит хотя бы разделить на комментарии к вопросам и к ответам. Я уже путаюсь в той структуре, которая сейчас есть.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: т.к. там достаточно много текста, [опубликовал отдельным вопросом и ответом](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1225/181472). Когда здесь утвердятся шаблоны, сделаю конфиг и для них.

Comment: Отдельный вопрос - круто! Действительно, можно попробовать разнести в разные ответы, если никто не выскажется против.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: ну вот я пока что выделил заголовками. Посмотрите, стало ли понятнее, надо ли разделять дальше (я-то всегда за разделение)

Comment: Существует также минорная проблема в этих комментариях, что если ТС прислушался и выполнил рекомендации из комментария, то комментарий остается в виде мусора, контроля за такими мусорными комментариями нет. Я как-то оттревожил напоминание о принятии ответа после того, как ответ был принят, пометил комментарий как устаревший, тревогу отклонили.

Comment: @YuraIvanov На старом движке мне приходили уведомления о любых изменениях в вопросе. К сожалению, сейчас такой возможности нет. На мой взгляд, по прошествию какого-то срока подобные комментарии следует удалять вне зависимости, внес ли автор изменения или нет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да, хотел добавить, что кнопка удалить на главном сайте отсутствует (только для своих комментариев она есть afaik), привилегии у меня все доступны, но видимо удаление комментариев доступно только ромбам. Про уведомления да, все грустно. У меня памяти на компе не хватает держать открытыми вкладки вопросов, по которым интересны изменения...

Comment: @YuraIvanov: видел юзерскрипт, создающий self-destruct комментарии. Вкладку держать открытой не надо было.

Comment: Добавил этот вопрос в [Часто задаваемые вопросы о StackOverflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/983)

Answer (score 10):

> ## Комментарии к вопросам

---

> #### Принятие ответа

**Проблема**: нет принятого ответа.

**Цель**: попросить автора вопроса отметить тот ответ «верным», который помог ему в решении задачи.

**Варианты**.

- Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

> #### Внесение уточняющих правок в ответ

**Проблема**: автор опубликовал ответ-ссылку, слишком короткий ответ, или ответ не подкрепленный обоснованием.

**Цель**: запросить у автора ответа уточняющую информацию.

**Варианты**.

- Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

> #### Вопрос, который стоит удалить

**Проблема**: иногда задаются вопросы, на улучшение которых необходимо потратить слишком много времени.

**Цель**: подсказать автору вопроса, что подобным вопросам не место на Stack Overflow на русском.

**Варианты**.

- Задавайте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться. (Комментарий публикуется при удалении вопроса.)

> #### Улучшение оформления вопроса

**Проблема**: вопрос оформлен небрежно.

**Цель**: подсказать автору, что вопрос следует улучшить.

**Варианты**.

- Если вы приведёте оформление вашего вопроса в порядок, вероятность получения ответа сильно возрастет.

> #### Учебные задания

**Проблема**: изучающие программирование задавая вопрос сообществу забывают/стесняются опубликовать свое "неверное" решение.

**Цель**: показать авторам таких вопросов, что решение можно найти лишь имея перед глазами проблему.

**Варианты**.

- Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации, добавьте описание конкретных проблем, с которыми вы столкнулись.

> #### Ответы на свои вопросы

**Проблема**: участник отписался в комментариях, что нашел решение, но само решение не опубликовал.

**Цель**: попросить автора опубликовать ответ, так как с большой вероятностью, он будет полезен сообществу в будущем.

**Варианты**.

- По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в `[ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)`. Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

> #### Вопрос на английском языке

**Проблема**: участники по разным причинам публикуют вопросы на английском.

Цель: 1) объяснить, что рабочий язык — русский 2) предложить выбор: перевести или перезадать на En.SO

- Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or `[ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)`. Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

> #### Дополнение сообщений

**Проблема**: новые участники сообщества используют сайт вопросов и ответов как форум - публикуют дополнения к вопросам или ответам в виде новых сообщений вместо внесения уточняющих правок.

**Цель**: подсказать новым участникам, как правильно строить дискуссию на Stack Overflow на русском.

**Варианты**.

- Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно `[рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6)`, вместо публикации комментариев.

---

> ## Комментарии к ответам

---

> #### Ответ, который стоит удалить

**Проблема**: иногда публикуются ответы, которые не несут пользы ни автору, ни сообществу, то есть их стоит удалить.

**Цель**: подсказать автору ответа, что необоснованным репликам не место на Stack Overflow на русском.

**Варианты**.

- Согласно правилам сообщества, публикуемые ответы должны быть содержательными, иначе они будут удаляться. (Комментарий публикуется при удалении ответа.)

> #### Ответы-ссылки

**Проблема**: участник видя, что может помочь коллеге, публикует ответ содержащий ссылку на другой ресурс без пояснений самого решения.

**Цель**: подсказать автору ответа, что подобные ответы — это «медвежья услуга» сообществу и попросить привести развернутое описание решения.

**Варианты**.

- Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить или изменить, и ответ потеряет ценность).

> #### Новый вопрос в ответе

**Проблема**: участник пытается общаться в стиле форума, публикуя свой вопрос в ответ к аналогичной проблеме.

**Цель**: подсказать новому участнику сообщества правила, согласно которым новый вопрос следует публиковать в виде вопроса, а не ответа.

**Варианты**.

- Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «`[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)`». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

> ## Комментарии для особых случаев
>
> #### Нежелательные сообщения

**Проблема**: случается, что даже самые стойкие из нас теряют самообладание, как результат, мы нехотя можем нагрубить коллеге.

**Цель**: подсказать товарищу, что грубость - это не решение проблемы.

**Варианты**.

- Пожалуйста, избегайте публикации подобных сообщений, иначе нам придется ограничить доступ к вашей учётной записи.

Comment: *Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?* — вообще-то это утвердительное предложение. вопросительное можно сделать, например, так: *сможете пояснить, на чём основано ваше утверждение?*

Comment: Не соглашусь. В принципе, в русском языке чуть ли не любое прделожение можно сделать вопросительным.

Comment: в принципе, можно. но … *неаккуратненько как-то*. ухо «режет».

Answer (score 9):

> ## Сервис StackOverflow-Translate

**Проблема:** Школьники/студенты просят перевести готовую лабораторку с одного языка программирования на другой

**Варианты:**

- Ваш вопрос — офтопик. Мы не выполняем учебные задания за учащихся целиком. Мы можем помочь по той или иной конструкции языка, но убедитесь, что вы знаете оба языка хотя бы на начальном уровне.
- Снежана, попросите лучше кого-то из одноклассников.
- Вопросы подобного плана не выполняются на этом ресурсе. Если вы затрудняетесь в каком-то конкретном месте, задайте вопрос по этой конструкции языка. В противном случае убедитесь, что вы знаете синтаксис обоих языков хотя бы на начальном уровне.

Comment: `[meta-tag:снежана]`, [meta-tag:снежана]

Comment: Помогите перевести программу с Brainfuck на [Petooh](https://github.com/Ky6uk/PETOOH). С меня как обычно. - Снежана

Answer (score 9):

Осторожно, ниже [нытье](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b5).

Просто копипастить комментарии — зло, особенно если нужно объяснить что-то нетривиальное. Если притвориться, что вам есть дело от того, кому вы пишете комментарий, то результат будет лучше.

## Неполный ответ

Рассмотрим пример: *Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?* Реакция юзера? Было: *Вот ссылка в гугл, лол.* Стало: *Вот ссылка в гугл, лол, потому что автор нуб, азаза.*

Какой комментарий будет более уместен?

> Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить *пример кода, объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы* и т. п.

**Внимание! Не сметь копипастить сообщение!** Если в ответе присутствует ссылка, уберите её упоминание из комментария; если присутствует указание на ошибку, уберите соответствующую рекомендацию.

Прочитав подобный комментарий, юзер поймёт, чего именно не хватает в ответе, а не будет сочинять абстрактное "обноснование". Ну, в идеале.

## Неправильное форматирование кода

Прошли времена, когда для форматирования кода существовала одна кнопка. Сейчас со всеми фрагментами, нетривиальными отступами и прочим наделать разных ошибок можно огромное количество.

Рассмотрим пример: *Если вы приведёте оформление вашего вопроса в порядок, вероятность получения ответа сильно возрастет.* Какое форматирование? В какой порядок? Вероятность на сколько граммов точно изменится?

Какой комментарий более уместен? Да множество, на все случаи жизни.

Например, вот распространённые проблемы с фрагментами кода:

> Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" (Ctrl+M) для добавления кода. Сообщение должно быть самодостаточным, ссылки на JSFiddle и подобные ресурсы могут служить только дополнением.

> Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для несамодостаточных кусков кода следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).

> Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для кусков кода не на JS/HTML/CSS следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).

> Форматируйте код с помощью отступов в 4 пробела, также вы можете выделить отрывок кода в сообщении и нажать сочетание Ctrl+K, чтобы добавить или удалить отступ.

Разнообразные проблемы с кодом в примере:

> Вставляйте код прямо в сообщение, а не ссылайтесь на внешние ресурсы. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

> Рекомендую ознакомиться со статьёй [Как создать краткий, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

> Оформление в виде `кода` следует использовать только для идентификаторов и небольших кусочков кода. В других случаях подобное выделение избыточно (в частности, в случае *названий библиотек*).

(Подставить нужное на место курсива.)

## Закрытие вопросов

После подарка свыше в виде запрета на мифические "вопросы-опросники", определение которым никто не может дать, которые каждый понимает по-своему — "проблема" с отсутствием подходящих причин для ушла в прошлое.

С комментариями можно не заморчиваться. Если вопрос не нравится, то он — опросник.

Comment: К неправильному форматированию кода не надо оставлять комментарий. Надо редактировать пост, изменив форматирование на правильное.

Comment: Кстати, с опросниками действительно есть проблема.

Comment: @TagirValeev Нужно и редактировать, и комментировать. Если всё делать за юзера и ничего не объяснять, то он ничему не научится.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Я сразу сказал, что добавление подобной причины — бред. Есть же обширный опыт большого СО, на котором перепробовали десятки причин для закрытия. Но нет, будем наступать на грабли, мы же особенные, у нас собственный путь. / По-хорошему надо бы пройтись через Data.SE по закрытиям и состряпать разгромный пост, но после коверкания абсолютно всех причин для закрытия я просто не знаю, с чего начать. Поломано ВСЁ.

Comment: @Discord, когда редактируешь, юзеру прилетает уведомление, что его пост отредактирован. Он может посмотреть историю правок и понять, что было изменено. Адекватный юзер так сделает и поймёт, в чём был неправ. Неадекватный и комментарию не внемлет.

Comment: @TagirValeev Фрагменты кода не очень-то объясняются в справке или форме редактирования. Как впихнуть код в элемент списка — тоже в справке отсутствует, вроде. В общем, есть много тонкостей, на которые лучше сразу указать, а не рассчитывать, что юзер будет раскапывать справку в поисках информации. Если бы он хотел искать, уже нашёл бы — до того, как запостить.

Answer (score 5):

> ## Комментарии к комментариям

---

> #### Уточнение вопроса или ответа в комментарии

**Проблема**: Пользователь опубликовал вопрос или ответ, забыл что-то указать в нём, и публикует дополнение в виде комментария к своему же посту.

**Цель**: Напомнить автору, что всегда есть возможность править собственные посты.

**Варианты**:

- Вы всегда можете править свои посты: для этого достаточно воспользоваться ссылкой `[edit]` под текстом вашего поста. Важную информацию лучше включать непосредственно в исходное сообщение.

Answer (score 2):

- Код картинкой:

  > `[Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)`

  > `[Почему в вопросе не следует выкладывать скриншоты кода/данных/ошибок?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)`

---

- Нет объяснения проблемы:

  > `Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.` *(из очереди проверок)*