# Древние принятые ответы-ссылки - удалять или продолжать взывать к автору за подробностями?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, принятые-ответы

**Дано:**

Старые (~год) ответы, представляющие собой ссылку на доки. В комментах есть оставшаяся без внимания просьба писать развёрнутые ответы. Ответ принят, голосов нет.

**Пример:** [Как убрать стандартные кнопки во время работы приложения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/376433/17609)

**Вопрос:**

Таки взывать к автору или жать на тревогу для удаления?

Comment: Я считаю, что ответ Nofate все-таки более полный, а мой его дополняет. Предлагаю принять его.

Comment: @NickVolynkin После последних правок готов согласиться)

Comment: Кстати, принятый ответ удалили, и теперь Дух Сообщества со временем удалит этот вопрос как вопрос с нулевым рейтингом без принятых ответов?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я за него проголосовал. Теперь, как я понимаю, он будет существовать вечно)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если ответ старый, можно:

- посмотреть, давно ли автор был на сайте, и, если он еще жив,  отправить комментарий;
- сходить по ссылке и, если ответ можно выразить относительно кратко, отредактировать ответ и пометить его как "общий";
- если ссылка недействительна - требовать удаления ответа;
- ничего не делать.

Comment: Если первый пункт не возымеет действия, а остальные не подходят через n дней можно удалять, так?

Comment: В случае с вашим примером ответ вполне можно спасти.

Comment: Удалять стоит, если контент по ссылку совсем недоступен.

Comment: Понял, спасибо)

Comment: *и пометить его как "общий"* — Nofate так привык быть модератором, что забыл, что нельзя просто так взять и отметить общими чужие ответы. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, верно. Но всегда можно кинуть тревогу и попросить.

Comment: *"если ссылка недействительна"* -- посмотреть закэшировали ли её wayback machine или yandex. Даже нерабочая ссылка может ключевые слова полезные содержать -- перенести в комментарий к вопросу, а ответ-ссылку удалить.

Answer (score 10):

**Как насчет мародёрства в отношении старых ответов?**

1. Открываете ссылку
2. Если ссылка не битая, пишете на её основе новый ответ
3. Если битая, просто пишете новый ответ
4. Отмечаете принятый ответ-ссылку как «не является ответом»
5. Profit!

**Если не можете написать ответ:**

1. Оставьте вопрос в покое,
2. Ничего там не трогайте,
3. Идите изучать тему вопроса.

**Если мучает совесть:**

Автор удалённого ответа продолжает видеть свой ответ и комментарии к нему. Он может отредактировать его и попросить модератора восстановить, после чего ответ снова вернет автору полученную репутацию. Насчет зелёной галочки не знаю, наверное останется, если другой ответ не был принят.

Comment: Это наилучший вариант, в случае, когда в теме разбираешься и написать можно кратко. В данном же случае я не осилю такой ответ. Как его поднять, чтобы кто-то ещё заметил?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: вариант: ссылку дублировать комментарием к вопросу, а ответ отметить тревогой.

Comment: Угу. Точно, ща так и сделаю)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, если не разбираетесь в данной теме, то лучше ничего там не трогайте.

Comment: @avp, я не то, что не разбираюсь, я скорее недостаточно разбираюсь, чтобы дать достойный ответ. Но точно знаю, что одной ссылки мало.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, тогда изучите тему и сами напишите еще один достойный ответ. И всегда поступайте только так.

Comment: @avp: включил ваши рекомендации )))

Answer (score 6):

В дополнение к ответу @Nofate и @Nick Volynkin:

1. **Ссылка является спамом.**
   Пометить соответствующей тревогой, добавить комментарий под ответом, возможно, отредактировать ответ, убрав ссылку.
2. **Ссылка не активна.**
   Оставить под ответом соответствующий комментарий для автора и проверяющих. Пометить тревогой "не является ответом". Автор в любом случае видит свои удалённые ответы и при желании сможет восстановить ответ, наполнив его актуальным содержимым.
3. **Ссылка активна и не является спамом, но автор не заходил последний месяц.**
   Перенести ссылку в комментарий к вопросу, оставить комментарий под ответом о том, что ссылка перенесена в комментарий и автор не является активным. Пометить сообщение тревогой "не является ответом".

   - *Дополнение.* Если ваших знаний достаточно, чтобы на основе ссылки создать ответ, лучше вместо переноса ссылки в комментарий создать ответ и указать ссылку в качестве источника.
4. **Ссылка активна и не является спамом, автор активен.**
   Оставить комментарий о том, что не стоит создавать ответы-ссылки и лучше приводить их в качестве источника (см. [шаблонные комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1222/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2)). Если на комментарий довольно долго нет реакции (неделю?), действовать по пункту 3.
5. **Ссылка активна, не является спамом, но не несёт пользы.**
   Если ваших знаний достаточно, чтобы заявить о бесполезности ссылки в отношении к этому вопросу, можно оставить комментарий о бесполезности ссылки и выставить тревогу "не является ответом".

*Дополнение ко всему ответу.* Простое удаление полезных ссылок не приносит пользы сообществу.

Как минимум, многие ссылки крайне полезны для более подробного ознакомления с темой вопроса, поэтому нужно сделать максимум для того, чтобы обработать такие ответы правильно.

При этом ответы-ссылки сложно назвать качественными, поэтому их стоит удалять или преобразовывать в более качественные, но при этом важно сохранять полезную информацию внутри сообщества.

Comment: как показывает практика, тревога "не является ответом" практически бесполезна. потому что многие трактуют ее как "не является *попыткой* ответа", а не "не является *правильным* ответом". что, в принципе, справедливо, иначе можно было бы массово раздавать тревоги на соседние сообщения, которые "являются ответом, но неправильным".

Comment: Поэтому я и отмечаю, что нужно публиковать комментарий вместе с тревогой, чтобы следующим проверяющим были понятны мотивы

Comment: даже если в комментарии будет написано "это неправильный ответ" - Alexander Barakin ткнет "выглядит нормально" - потому что это *ответ* - и формально тревога "не является ответом" к нему неприменима. и я с ним, кстати, согласен.

Comment: @PashaPash Содержимое комментария, конечно, стоит делать более содержательное. Комментарий "это неправильный ответ" не сообщает проверяющему о мотивах. Если ссылка бесполезна, можно написать, например, "Содержимое сайта по ссылке не относится к теме вопроса" или что-то подобное, в зависимости от ситуации

Comment: а если содержимое относится к теме вопроса, но не решает проблему, поставленную в вопросе?

Comment: Тогда такой ссылке как раз и место в комментарии к вопросу. Комментарий к ответу при этом должен указать на то, что ссылка перенесена в комментарий и ответ можно удалять.