# Древние непринятые ответы-ссылки с нулевым рейтингом - удалять или оставлять как есть?

Tags: обсуждение

По мотивам [Древние принятые ответы-ссылки - удалять или продолжать взывать к автору за подробностями?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1426/):

Что делать с *принятыми* ответами ссылками более-менее понятно - они полезны, и просто так удалять их не стоит.

Но что делать с *непринятыми* ответами-ссылками, за которые за несколько лет никто не проголосовал за?

Примеры:

- [Отправить post запрос на сторонний сайт и получить ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/207624/)
- [Содержит ли строка допустимое имя файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/133392/)

Оба ответа имели рейтинг 0 в момент попадания их в очередь.

- Стоит ли отмечать такие ответы тревогами?
- Стоит ли вчитыватся в содержание ссылок?
- Стоит ли переносить такие ссылки в комментарии?
- Стоит ли переносить информацию по ссылке в новый ответ?

Т.е. что делать с ответами-ссылками, которые, будь они созданы сегодня, попали бы в очередь VLQ, где их бы удалили с комментарием "ответ по ссылке может стать недействительным"? Стоит ли сам факт поста ссылки давным-давно, а не сегодня, того, чтобы оставить ее жить?

Comment: Добавлю ссылку [на свой ответ](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1544/177596) к связанному вопросу, который, как мне кажется, подходит и в этом случае. Явно дублировать его здесь не вижу смысла.

Answer (score 4):

[Правила сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) явно указывают, что ответ, состоящий только из ссылки, ответом не является:

> Ответы, которые совершенно не отвечают на вопрос, могут быть удалены. Это относится к ответам, которые:
>
> - ...
> - являются всего лишь ссылкой на другой сайт;
> - ...

Поэтому со старым ссылками стоит поступать так же, как с новыми - ставить на них тревогу

> вопрос необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством
>
> Ответ имеет серьезные проблемы с форматированием или контентом. Ответ вряд ли удастся исправить с помощью правок, поэтому его необходимо удалить.

это отправит ответ в очередь "Сообщения низкого качества".

---

Разбор очереди VLQ - это не *голосование* "мне нравится". Это добровольная помощь в модерировании сайта - проверке сообщений на *соответствие правилам*.

При просмотре ответов-ссылок в очереди стоит:

- Если автор давно не активен и вам не жалко времени и сил - перенести суть ответа с сайта по ссылке в тело ответа. Правка выбросит ответ из очереди.
- Если автор активен - голосовать за удаление с соответствующим комментарием.
- Если по ссылке что-то совсем не отвечающее на вопрос - голосовать за удаление с соответствующим комментарием.
- Если вы ощущаете, что недостаточно компетентны в конкретной области, и не можете определить ценность - пропустить.

Чего точно делать не стоит:

- Нажимать "Выглядит нормально". Потому что ответ, прямо противоречащий правилам сайта не "выглядит нормально" по определению.

Тестовые проверки в стадии беты отключены. Никакой валидации ваших действий при разборе очереди не проводится. Поэтому иногда стоит возвращаться назад при провеке очереди и оценивать, насколько ваше решение совпало с решением остальных проверяющих. Если вы отметили "выглядит нормально" то, что 6 других пользователей решили рекомендовать к удалению - значит вы скорее всего нажали не ту кнопку.

Стоит помнить, что сообщения не удаляются безвозвратно. Кнопка "удалить" - это на самом деле кнопка "скрыть от пользователей с низкой репутацией". Удаление никак не "удаляет ценную информацию". Если вы считаете воскрешение ссылок и перенос их достаточно полезным занятием - вы можете сделать это и после удаления ответа.

Comment: Переносить содержимое из сайта в ответ довольно друдоёмкое занятие и не совсем корректная правка. Лучше оформлять подобное в виде отдельного ответа, при этом можно оставить комментарий наподобие "Раскрыл информацию по ссылке в отдельном ответе, этот ответ-ссылку следует удалить".

Comment: Почти все законы не имеют обратной силы. Если правило было введено позже, то это не означает, что всё что ему не соответствует должно быть удалено.

Comment: @Qwertiy здесь ситуация другая. Здесь нет "законов", здесь просто идёт попытка убрать некачественный контент. Думаю, во времена ХешКода ответ-ссылка был столь же некачественным (хоть и приемлемым), как и сейчас. Ответы-ссылки несут крайне мало полезной информации, поэтому даже старые ссылки нужно переоформить и выкосить среди них плохие и нерабочие.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, с формулировкой "переоформить и выкосить среди них плохие и нерабочие" я согласен. Я не согласен именно с вариантом удалять все ссылки без разбора.

Comment: @Qwertiy Если жалко удаленных ссылок - можно мониторить "недавно удаленные" в инструментах модератора и переносить удаленную информацию из них в новые ответы. Вопрос, кстати, не касается удаления всех ссылок без разбора. Только старых ссылок с нулевым или отрицательным рейтингом.

Answer (score 2):

Удаляя ссылку без какого-либо её дублирования мы заведомо теряем некоторую информацию. Причём, если ответ оставить, то в худшем случае мы когда-то в будущем потеряем эту же информацию. Поэтому удалять ссылки безвозвратно неправильно.

В случае новых ответов есть вероятность, что автор дополнит ответ, а для старых это маловероятно. Поэтому я считаю, что надо либо поступать с ними так же, [как с принятыми](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1428/178988), либо оставлять.

Comment: Тогда и ответы вида "погугли по слову ZZZ" не стоит удалять - они тоже несут в себе информацию! Удаление сообщения на SO не безвозвратно. Движок вообще не позволяет ничего окончательно удалить. 0 голосов на несколько лет, при тысячах просмотров, означает, что ссылка не слишком полезной. то, что она скроется от пользователей - пойдет сайту только на пользу - уберет лишний шум.

Comment: @PashaPash, "ответам" погугли по такому-то слову самое место в комментариях. А их главный плюс, что их можно дать быстро, что конкретно для автора может быть полезно. Либо если вопрос слишком широкий и всем лень писать нормальный ответ.