# Реальная проблема сайта - вопросы с хэшкод

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

В то время как народ решает проблемы меток, мета-меток и over9000-меток есть пласт вопросов перешедших с хэша. Вот на вскидку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как по названию вопроса понять его полезность\уникальность?

Просто идти циклом и править? По мне так 99% нужно удалить.

### ВТОРОЙ ВОПРОС

Что делать с вопросами на которые даны в принципе адекватные ответы, но авторы исчезли\не отметили ответом.

Опять же отсылка к старым датам

### UPD

про старые вопросы - что делать? звать модератора? и там на его усмотрение удаление или принятие ответа?

как понимаю модератор тут не в силах помочь - остается только закрытие.

или движок СО предусматривает же правленные ответы помещать вверх? то есть можно показать вопросы общественности и уж она там наголосует\наминусует

Comment: Модератор не может принять ответ. Механизм обычный: если старый вопрос или ответ не удовлетворяет критериям качества - минусовать, голосовать за закрытие.

Comment: то есть один путь - тревога за закрытие? ибо вряд ли люди из 2011 опомнятся, зарегаются и отметят ответ правильным

Comment: Если вопрос плохой - закрывать как любой плохой вопрос. Если вопрос просто старый и без принятого ответа - закрывать не нужно.

Comment: и будет вечно в выборке вопросы меньше 8 букв или же вопросы с непринятыми ответами и стата меньше 80. про то и речь - как бороться.

Comment: Если у вопроса есть положительный баланс по ответам - система считает его принятым.

Comment: Оставили бы их (старые вопросы) в покое, лучше на новые отвечайте.

Answer (score 11):

**По первому вопросу:**

Наследие ХэшКода - это не проблема, это - то, благодаря чему RU.SO вообще увидел свет. Над старыми вопросами надо работать, выкидывать мусор, улучшать то, что не выкинули. На мой субъективный взгляд, этим так или иначе занимаются больше людей, чем проблемами "меток, мета-меток и over9000-меток". Про это тут:

- [Статистика отвеченных вопросов и актуальные задачи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1339)

**По второму вопросу**

Если ответ адекватный, поставьте +1. Если не очень адекватный, попробуйте улучшить (при наличии желания). Этот вопрос тоже обсуждали:

- [Древние принятые ответы-ссылки - удалять или продолжать взывать к автору за подробностями?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1426/)
- [Древние непринятые ответы-ссылки с нулевым рейтингом - удалять или оставлять как есть?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1545/)
- [Нужно ли отвечать на вопросы, заданные достаточно давно?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156/)
- [Может ли модератор принять ответ на вопрос за автора?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/167/)