# Ответ - ссылка не приветствуется?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика, ответы, ссылки

В курсе, что ответы-ссылки не приветствуются, но всегда ли всё так однозначно?
Обычно подобные ответы минусуются/удаляются, но...

Подобный вопрос и на [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) поднимался, и не раз. Что-то подобное [обсуждалось](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1426/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80) и у нас. Но всё же..

Предположим, что по ссылке ответ на вопрос, но на английском. Автор ответа на SO английского не знает. Ему не стоит публиковать такой ответ? Или как комментарий к вопросу писать?

Или же по ссылке ответ на вопрос, но автор ответа в теме не разбирается и не может на основании ссылки дать развёрнутый ответ, так же не стоит публиковать?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Основная проблема ссылок - протухание. Год-два и все. Каждый день у нас удаляется вязанка мертвых ссылок. А их еще надо отыскать.

> скажем, с английского SO, где эта ссылка в ответе. Если есть базовые знания eng, то он мог понять, что ссылка - ответ на вопрос. Но перевести для ru SO не может.

Можно кинуть в комментарии с просьбой перевести. Ссылки на английский СО это несколько надежнее прочих ссылок. Но и они временами становятся недоступны.

> когда она протухнет - это уже другое дело. Вопрос в том, что если человек вообще не даст ответа, то создатель вопроса останется без решения. Если человек публикует ответ с ссылкой, то есть шанс, что она поможет автору вопроса.

Тут дело в том, что задача СО не только дать ответ здесь и сейчас, а, что гораздо важнее, накопить знания для других.

> а если ссылка на русскую статью, но автор вообще не в теме вопроса и не может раскрыть её в ответе?

Если отвечающий не в теме вопроса, зачем отвечать? Если кроме ссылки сказать нечего, лучше оставить ее в комментарии, мол, это похоже на то, что вам нужно. А там, нередко, и сам спрашивающий оформит ответ с решением (это не возбраняется, а приветствуется).

Answer (score 9):

В общем и целом выскажусь *против* ответов-ссылок и комментариев-ссылок. Как всегда, есть за и против. За:

- автора вопроса, получает хоть какой-либо ответ, который, возможно, поможет в решении задачи.

Доводы *против* уже обсуждались не один раз. На мой взгляд, наиболее важно обратить внимание на утверждение о том, в чем видят ценность Stack Overflow пользователи (не участники) сайта. Наиболее часто я слышу примерно такой отзыв.

> Я люблю Stack Overflow не просто по тому, что на сайте можно найти *развернутое* объяснение решения, но и *реальный уникальный опыт* конкретного человека.

В контексте этого отзыва, давайте вспомним, что на Stack Overflow вопрос задается не для того, кто на него хочет ответить, а ответ публикуется, не для того, кто задал вопрос. И вопрос, и ответ публикуются на сайте для сотен и тысяч наших коллег, которые в будущем попадут на сайт из поисковика в поисках решения.

Как вы видите, ответы-ссылки и комментарии–ссылки не вписываются в модель Stack Overflow именно по мнению людей, для которых мы все делаем – для наших коллег, которые используют созданные нами знания.

Также, про исключения из [ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1807/6) [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/). На мой взгляд, было бы здорово не иметь ни одного исключения.

Особенно подчеркну про ссылки на ответы из англоязычного сообщества. На данный момент, Stack Overflow на английском – это отдельный сайт, откуда вопросы и ответы могут быть удалены. Если вы нашли подходящий ответ на сайте, пожалуйста, напишите минимальный самодостаточный ответ, дополнив его ссылкой на источник. Нет ничего плохого, если ваш ответ будет похож на оригинал.

В дополнение. Обычно, видя ответы-ссылки или *комментарии-ссылки* я добавляю следующий комментарий:

> Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Пожалуйста, помните, что на Stack Overflow мы в первую очередь заботимся не о тех, кто задает вопрос, а о тех, кто в будущем столкнется с аналогичной проблемой.

Comment: Ладно ответы, они действительно должны содержать больше, чем ссылку. Но если у меня есть только ссылка и нет времени изучать тему и писать подробный ответ, то этой ссылке самое место в комментарии.

Comment: Комментарии на enSO обычно содержат вопросы, близкие по тематике, да даже если и точно такой же вопрос, там иногда есть большое количество ответов и полезных комментариев к ответам. Собрать это в один пост-ответ иногда довольно сложно, да и обсуждение на enSO не замораживается, могут быть добавлены новые сведения. Поэтому я считаю, что комментарии со ссылкой на похожие вопросы на enSO нужны, так как **они не добавляются самостоятельно** из-за обособленного положения ruSO.

Answer (score 3):

Считаю, что ответы-ссылки не должны использоваться, в первую очередь из-за того, что как было отмечено выше, они имею свойство "протухать", но должны быть исключения.

Если ответ на вопрос расположен на внешнем ресурсе, его нужно **скопировать целиком с обязательным указанием первоисточника и автора**, тем более, что именно этого требуют правила большинства таких информационных форумов и сайтов.

Если язык источника отличается от русского, то в общем случае **отвечающий должен быть способен перевести ответ, ведь в противном случае он в принципе не может быть уверен что, информация которую он представляет в ответе применима** к теме вопроса.

В исключительных случаях, как то:

1. Первоисточник имеет значительный объем и его перевод - отдельный
   большой труд;
2. Отвечающий абсолютно уверен в том, что статья содержит
       ответ на вопрос, но не имеет времени, возможности перевести в
       настоящий момент;

возможно имеет смысл все таки оставлять ссылку на внешний ресурс с указанием авторских прав и просьбой к сообществу осуществить перевод целиком или связанных с темой фрагментов в обозримые сроки. Это максимум, что можно предпринять. Если содержимое по ссылке в итоге окажется не переведенным и не перенесенным, то, в случае, если ответ единственный, встает выбор между наличием ответа-ссылки и отсутствием какого либо-ответа вообще. Как пользователь я бы выбрал первый вариант.

Answer (score 2):

В целом - не приветствуются, но есть и исключения:

- [Что делать, когда просят ссылки, а потом получают ссылки?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1638/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8)
- Ссылки на подходящие вопросы ruSO/SO
- Ссылки на библиотеки/программы, где само имя является достаточным для поиска
- С большой осторожностью ссылки на видеоуроки

В общем, желательно смотреть по ценности, полезности и релевантности материалов и реагировать соответствующим образом. Неправильно говорить, что любая ссылка - это заведомо плохо. Но, если это возможно, то к ссылке должна прилагаться информация, достаточная, как минимум, для поиска соответствующих сведений в гугле.

Comment: Ссылки на подходящие вопросы лучше кидать в комментарии к вопросу/ответу. Ссылки на библиотеки-программы стоит обязательно оставлять вместе с названием (бывает, что бросают просто ссылку на сайт).

Comment: "Ссылки на подходящие вопросы ruSO" являются поводом для закрытия как дубликата. В противном случае рискуем получить хорошие ответы разбросанные по нескольким вопросам, а они должны быть в одном месте. На простом so вопрос могут удалить (хотя бы сам автор), либо у спрашивающего может быть плохо с языком (вы португальский знаете? а если я на ваши вопросы буду кидать ответы с pt.so?). В целом же - периодически встречаю ответы с ссылкой на офдоки по php, при этом сами ссылки битые. Так это офдоки, которые вообще редко трогаются. Так что ссылки без текста в ответе не нужны

Answer (score 2):

По сравнению с *полным* отсутствием ответа, ответ-ссылка, особенно если ссылка содержит название библиотеки (или другое ключевое слово сильно помогающее в поиске решения) и особенно, если сама ссылка ведёт на хорошую документацию, наличие ответа-ссылки является положительным.

Например, если вопрос как сделать http запрос в Питоне с автоматической поддержкой gzip/deflate Content-Encoding, то ответ-ссылка http://docs.python-requests.org/ лучше чем ничего.

Естественно, что *самодостаточный ответ является более предпочтительным*. К сожалению, текущий интерфейс модерирования подталкивает к удалению  ответов-ссылок вместо их редактирования, с целью улучшения, например, несложно добавить пример кода с результатом для упомянутого Питон-вопроса:

```
import requests

print(requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get').text)
```

Если ответ не является вредным и автор реагирует на комментарии, которые указывают на технические неточности в ответе, то я бы не стал даже минусовать такой ответ (а тем более не нужно удалять).

Если отредактировать (чтобы улучшить) нет возможности/знаний, то лучше ответ-ссылку в комментарий перенести, чем удалять его.

> Предположим, что по ссылке ответ на вопрос, но на английском. Автор ответа на SO английского не знает. Ему не стоит публиковать такой ответ?

Даже если автор английского не знает, другие пользователи сайта могут получить пользу от ссылки.

> Или как комментарий к вопросу писать?

Можно сказать, что следует комментарий оставить, если нет времени/желания опубликовать полноценный ответ, но это отсекает людей, которые не могут комментировать ещё и усугубляет проблему, что люди оставляют ответы в комментариях -- если это ответ (даже если ответ можно улучшить), то следует его публиковать как ответ. Хотя опять таки подсказка в виде ссылки в комментарии -- лучше чем ничего.

> Или же по ссылке ответ на вопрос, но автор ответа в теме не разбирается и не может на основании ссылки дать развёрнутый ответ, так же не стоит публиковать?

Если информация может помочь в решении проблемы, то следует опубликовать. Если есть сомнения, что решение верное по ссылке, можно это также упомянуть.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ, содержащий ссылку и более ничего, конечно не является полноценным ответом. Но, лично для меня, идеальным ответом является что-то типа пары строк кода, показывающие способ решения вопроса и, (часто обязательно) ссылка на авторитетный первоисточник, типа мануала, стандарта языка или официальной документации. Просто потому, что в квалификации отвечающего я никогда не могу быть стопроцентно уверен.

П.С. Небольшой оффтоп. Мне кажется, что тот же stackoverflow.com выглядит значительно доброжелательней русскоязычного, в особенности к новичкам. Даже на довольно простые вопросы можно найти развернутые ответы с отсылкой к "первоисточникам". Кроме того, на 80% процентов вопросов, ответ находится 1-ой/2-ой ссылкой в гугле при правильной формулировке вопроса на английском языке. Из этих ссылок - больше половины - как раз на англоязычный SO.

Comment: Про доброжелательность к новичкам en SO вы, конечно, загнули )

Comment: @Suvitruf, вполне возможно, я не читаю его подряд, но то что гуглится, выглядит доброжелательно. Даже в случае довольно примитивных вопросов.

Comment: @Suvitruf Систематическая ошибка выжившего?

Comment: @PashaPash, вполне вероятно, спорить не буду. Чтобы что-то возразить или согласиться нужно читать подряд, а времени нет.