# Ответы-ссылки на enSO

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

Как обитатели Stack Overflow на русском относятся к ответам, состоящим лишь из одной(их) ссылки(ок) на английский Stack Overflow или какой-либо другой сайт сети Stack Exchange?

Если так подумать, с одной стороны, enSO — тоже база знаний, и её доступность коррелирует с доступностью ruSO (я так думаю). С другой стороны к такой ссылке применимы все аргументы со страниц справки об ответах-ссылках.

Как в дальнейшем поступать с подобными ответами: оставлять как есть или отмечать тревогой, голосовать за закрытие?

Стоит отметить, что в основном, такие сообщения остались ещё со времён Хеш-Кода. Вот только некоторые из них:

- [Что значит аргумент @{u} в Git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/263414/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-u-%d0%b2-git/264207#264207)
- [Изменить размер текста в табах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/316377/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%85/316588#316588)
- [Недоступные элементы в контекстном меню](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/374857/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e/374953#374953)
- [Получить id итема в listview проведя пальцем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/241397/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-id-%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b2-listview-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bc/241400#241400)

---

[Похожий мета-вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1805). Настоящий вопрос отличается от указанного обсуждением ссылок на конкретный сайт — [stackoveflow.com](https://stackoveflow.com). Всё же enSO — не просто какой-то паршивый бложик забытого богом разраба...

Comment: Переводить же надо и постить ответом...

Comment: Мне не нравятся. Хочется помочь, но нет ответа лучше, чем ссылка -- дай ее в комментарии

Comment: на enSO вопросы/ответы тоже удаляются

Comment: Поскольку на данный момент Stack Overflow на английском является по сути отдельным сайтом, его следует рассматривать на ряду со всеми остальными сайтами. Ответы ссылки – не приветствуются, и должны либо улучшаться, либо удаляться вовсе.

Comment: Здесь Stack Overflow **на русском**. Посему, ответы здесь ожидаются тоже на русском, за исключением чисто технических текстов (программного кода, трейсов, и т. п.). Ссылка на ответ на enSO не является ответом на русском языке.