# Как в "Фрагмент кода (Stack Snippet)" писать React код с поддержкой JSX?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, ответы, сниппеты, вопросы-по-метке

## Предисловие

Оригинальный вопрос-ответ: [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support)

В последнее время стал чаще замечать как вопрошающие показывают свой код на React, а потом отдельными скриншотами или дополнительными кусками кода показывают результат работы их кода и какая у них проблема или ещё хуже оставляют ссылки на сторонние ресурсы, куда отвечающие должны переходить чтобы запустить код и смотреть на результат выполнения. Тоже самое делают и отвечающие, оставляют кусок кода и ссылку на сторонный источник, куда вопрошающий должен перейти,  запустить и убедиться, что его проблема решена. Кроме того уже были [обсуждения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1805/385375), почему ответы ссылки - это плохо. Чего греха таить, я сам так делал, пока не надоело :) Ну и как вы понимаете в поисках информации я наткнулся на указанный выше вопрос-ответ. Не найдя ответа на этот вопрос в русской мете, решил поделиться своим переводом

Прошу принять тот факт, что это не будет 100%-ым переводом слово в слово. Будут дополнения к тексту, небольшие изменения содержания, а некоторые части могут быть полностью вырезаны. Можете считать что это основано на оригинальном вопрос-ответе, а не является его полной копией на русском языке :)

И так начнём:

## Вопрос

В редакторе "Фрагмент кода" есть возможность включения библиотеки React, но как на самом деле создать "Фрагмент кода", где можно писать React код с поддержкой JSX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это пошаговое руководство, сначала будет краткое содержание, затем подробности с картинками. После подробных инструкций будет несколько "Фрагмент кода" (далее ФК) для демонстрации

## Краткое содержание

1. Откройте редактирование ФК редактора нажав на [image: Иконка ФК] кнопку на панели инструментов или вместо этого можете нажать комбинацию `CTRL + M`
2. Выберите нужную версию React из раскрывающегося списка слева

   Если вы не видите нужную версию в списке, то смотрите подробности ниже. Так же прошу заметить, что для использования хуков вам нужна **версия React не ниже 16.8.** На данный момент (май 2022) последняя версия в списке - это 16.6.3
3. Установите флажок на **Use BabelJS / ES2015**

   Об этом явно не говорится, но - это именно то, что позволяет использовать синтаксис JSX, т.к. используемая конфигурация Babel включает обработку JSX

   К сожалению, версию Babel, которая используется, не обновляли годами, поэтому не поддерживаются сокращенные фрагменты (`<></>`) и `async / await`. Вы можете включить их, если они нужны, просто это будет неудобно

   Обсуждения на тему "Почему не обновляют верисю Babel" можете прочитать на английском SO [тут](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386097/why-wont-this-snippet-with-async-await-work-here-on-stack-overflow-snippet-edit) и [тут](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386096/update-the-version-of-babel-standalone-and-others-used-by-stack-snippets)
4. Если вы **НЕ** собираетесь использовать консоль в ФК, то самое время снять флажок с **Показать консоль**
5. Если вам нужны дополнительные библиотеки, то используйте кнопку **Добавить внешнюю библиотеку** (или просто теги `script` и `link`)
6. Добавьте свой код в секцию JavaScript
7. Если вы используете хуки, вы можете либо использовать их непосредственно из React (React.useState и т.д.), либо использовать деструктуризацию в начале (так вы получите более приближенный к `import`-у вариант):

   ```
   const {useState} = React;
   ```
8. В конце вашего кода напишите вызов `ReactDOM.render`, сообщающий, что отображать и где

   Если вы используете вывод в консоль, то убедитесь что в секции HTML объявлен элемент и выбран этот элемент при вызове `ReactDOM.render`. Если нет, то вы можете рендерить прямо в `body`, если хотите. (При визуализации в `body` не работает вывод в консоль потому что элемент консоли перезаписывается)
9. Вы готовы запустить свой React/JSX код! Нажмите на кнопку **Запустить**

   Обратите внимание, что может быть небольшая задержка при загрузке скриптов и транспиляции JSX, прежде чем ваши результаты появятся в секции Результат. Как и в случае с любым фрагментом кода, убедитесь, что он работает так, как вы хотите (проверьте веб-консоль, если вы не используете консоль в ФК), и показывает то, что вы хотите продемонстрировать (вашу конкретную проблему, если вы задаёте вопрос, а если если публикуете ответ то вопрос или решение)

## Подробное содержание

1. Откройте редактирование ФК редактора нажав на [image: Иконка ФК] кнопку на панели инструментов или вместо этого можете нажать комбинацию `CTRL + M`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Выберите нужную версию React открыв раскрывающееся меню слева:

   [image: Расположение кнопки для выбора версии React]

   и нажав на нужную версию из списка:

   [image: Выбор нужной версии React]

   После выбора нужной версии React (для примера была выбрана версия 16.6.3) вы увидете следующие 2 строчки:

   ```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
   ```

   в секции HTML:

   [image: Скрипты после подключения React]

   Чтобы использовать хуки и тому подобное, вам понадобятся более поздние версии React. Вы можете подключить последнюю версию из CDN (например: https://cdnjs.com/). Используйте версии "UMD". Например, чтобы использовать версию x.y.z надо просто заменить 16.6.3 на нужную и доступную вам (для примера показана 18.1.0):

   ```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
   ```

   в секции HTML:

   [image: Скрипты после изменения версии React]

   Обратите внимание, что после выбора версии, не доступной в выпадающем списке, исчезает надпись с кнопки открывающий этот список:

   [image: На кнопке раскрывающий список версий React отсутсвует надпись]

   но не бойтесь - это нормально, всё будет работать корректно, если вы выбрали доступную версию
3. Установите флажок на **Use BabelJS / ES2015**
   [image: Расположение включателя/выключателся встроенного Babel]

   Об этом явно не говорится, но - это именно то, что позволяет использовать синтаксис JSX, т.к. используемая конфигурация Babel включает обработку JSX

   К сожалению, версию Babel, которая используется, не обновляли годами, поэтому некоторые фичи не доступны. Например:

   - не поддерживаются сокращенные фрагменты (`<></>`), но это легко решается заменой сокращенного синткасиса на развёрнутый (`<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>`):

     Меняем такой синтаксис:

     ```
     <>
     // Ваш код
     </>
     ```

     на такой:

     ```
     <React.Fragment>
     // Ваш код
     </React.Fragment>
     ```
   - не поддерживется синтаксис `async / await`. Тут к сожалению придётся переписать на синтаксис `.then().catch()`:

     Меняем такой синтаксис:

     ```
     const func = async () => {
         try {
           const response = await fetch(/*url and data*/);
           /*Your code*/
         } catch(e) {
           console.log(e.message);  
         }
     }
     ```

     на такой:

     ```
     const func = () => {
        fetch(/*url and data*/)
        .then(response => {
          /*Your code*/
        })
        .catch(e => {
           console.log(e.message);
        })
     }
     ```

   Ну и дальше так вверх по цепочке пока ваш код не будет выглядеть как синхронный код

   На самом деле я нашёл небольшой лайфхак, как обойти все ограничения встроенного Babel и писать код со всеми фичами :) Но об этом я расскажу в самом конце после примеров т.к. этот лайфхак никак не помогает писать более современный код в секции JavaScript
4. Если вы **НЕ** собираетесь использовать консоль в ФК, то самое время снять флажок с **Показать консоль**

   [image: Расположение включателя/выключателся встроенной консоли]
5. Если вам нужны дополнительные библиотеки, то используйте кнопку **Добавить внешнюю библиотеку** (или просто теги `script` и `link`)
   [image: Расположение кнопки добавления дополнительных библиотек]

   После нажатия откроется диалоговое окно куда нужно будет вставить ссылку

   [image: Диалоговое окно для вставки ссылки на внешние ресурсы]

   Конечно, можно и без этой кнопки, вручную прописывать теги `script` или `link`, но в случае с кнопкой вам просто надо вставить ссылку и он сам автоматически поймёт какой тег надо использовать
6. Добавьте свой код в нужные секции
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
7. Если вы используете хуки, вы можете либо использовать их непосредственно из React (React.useState и т.д.):

   ```
   const [s, setX] = React.useState();
   ```

   либо использовать деструктуризацию в начале (так вы получите более приближенный к `import`-у вариант) и потом использовать в любом месте кода:

   ```
   const {useState} = React;
   /*Some code*/
   const [s, setX] = useState();
   ```

   Более подробные примеры, с использованием хуков, будут ниже
8. В конце вашего кода напишите вызов `ReactDOM.render`, сообщающий, что отображать и где

   - Если вы используете вывод в консоль, то убедитесь что в секции HTML объявлен элемент и выбран этот элемент при вызове `ReactDOM.render`. К примеру так:

     HTML:

     ```
      <!-- Some code -->
      <div id="react"></div>
      <!-- Some code -->
     ```

     JS:

     ```
      /* Some code */
      /* At the end of code */
      const {createRoot} = ReactDOM;
      const rootContainer = document.querySelector('#react');

      if (rootContainer === null) throw new Error('There is no root container');

      const root = createRoot(rootContainer);

      root.render(<App />);
     ```
   - Если нет, то вы можете рендерить прямо в `body`, если хотите. (При визуализации в `body` не работает вывод в консоль потому что элемент консоли перезаписывается):

     HTML:

     ```
      <!-- Some code -->
     ```

     JS:

     ```
      /* Some code */
      /* At the end of code */
      const {createRoot} = ReactDOM;
      const rootContainer = document.body;

      if (rootContainer === null) throw new Error('There is no root container');

      const root = createRoot(rootContainer);

      root.render(<App />);
     ```
9. Вы готовы запустить свой React/JSX код! Нажмите на кнопку **Запустить**

   Обратите внимание, что может быть небольшая задержка при загрузке скриптов и транспиляции JSX, прежде чем ваши результаты появятся в секции Результат. Как и в случае с любым фрагментом кода, убедитесь, что он работает так, как вы хотите (проверьте веб-консоль, если вы не используете консоль в ФК), и показывает то, что вы хотите продемонстрировать (вашу конкретную проблему, если вы задаёте вопрос, а если если публикуете ответ то вопрос или решение)

## Примеры

### Пример кода, с рендерингом в конкретный элемент и с выводом в консоль

```js
const {createRoot} = ReactDOM;

// Пример функционального компонента
const RedText = ({text}) => {
  console.log('Functional component');

  return <span class="red-text">{text}</span>
}

// Пример классового компонента
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('Class component');

    return (
      <div>
        <RedText text="Some text 1" />
        <br/>
        <RedText text="Some text 2" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Рендеринг
const rootContainer = document.querySelector('#react');

if (rootContainer === null) throw new Error('There is no root container');

const root = createRoot(rootContainer);

root.render(<App />);
```

```css
.red-text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

### Пример кода, с рендерингом в элемент `body` (вывод в консоль не покажется)

```js
const {createRoot} = ReactDOM;

// Пример функционального компонента
const RedText = ({text}) => {
  console.log('Functional component');

  return <span class="red-text">{text}</span>
}

// Пример классового компонента
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('Class component');

    return (
      <div>
        <RedText text="Some text 1" />
        <br/>
        <RedText text="Some text 2" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Рендеринг
const rootContainer = document.body;

if (rootContainer === null) throw new Error('There is no root container');

const root = createRoot(rootContainer);

root.render(<App />);
```

```css
.red-text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

### Пример кода, с использованием хуков, фрагмента и с выводом в консоль

```js
const {createRoot} = ReactDOM;
const {useState} = React;

// Пример функционального компонента
const Counter = ({initialValue}) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialValue);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`(Render) initialValue was ${initialValue}`);
  })

  return <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>You clicked me {count} time(s)</button>
}

// Пример классового компонента
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Counter initialValue={0} />
        <br/>
        <Counter initialValue={1} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

// Рендеринг
const rootContainer = document.querySelector('#react');

if (rootContainer === null) throw new Error('There is no root container');

const root = createRoot(rootContainer);

root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

### Пример кода, с использованием дополнительной библиотеки [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction) ([пример из документации использованый ниже](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#as-prop-api))

```js
const {createRoot} = ReactDOM;
const {Col, Row, Button} = ReactBootstrap;

// Пример функционального компонента
const ExternalLibrary = () => {
  return (
    <Row className="mx-0">
      <Button as={Col} variant="primary">Button #1</Button>
      <Button as={Col} variant="secondary" className="mx-2">Button #2</Button>
      <Button as={Col} variant="success">Button #3</Button>
    </Row>
  )
}

// Пример классового компонента
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ExternalLibrary />
    );
  }
}

// Рендеринг
const rootContainer = document.querySelector('#react');

if (rootContainer === null) throw new Error('There is no root container');

const root = createRoot(rootContainer);

root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>

<div id="react"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin></script>
```

## Вишенка на тортике :)

Если ну уж очень сильно хочется писать на современном синтаксисе React (с поддержкой `async / await`, сокращённого синтаксиса фрагментов (`<></>`) и т.д.), то это легко можно устроить, если писать JS код в HTML секции.

### Шаги

1. После подключения нужной версии React, надо добавить скрипт со ссылкой на нужную и доступную версию Babel

   ```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Ниже всего лишь надо добавить тег `script` с аттрибутом `type` со значением `"text/babel"` и вписать туда свой код. Даже не надо ставить галочку на **Use BabelJS / ES2015**

   ```
    <script type="text/babel">
    /* Some code*/
    </script>
   ```
3. Не забываем инструкции по выводу данных в консоль, подробно описанных в 8-ом пункте :)

Единнственный минус, что я заметил - это то что когда указывается аттрибут `type="text/babel"`, то редактор начинает показывать JS код как обычный текст, т.е. без подсветки, и если нажать на кнопку **Привести в порядок**, то редактор весь код превратит в одну строчку. Потому во время разработки надо убрать этот аттрибут, а перед запуском обратно вставить. Главное после публикации кода подсветка вернётся назад и удобно будет читать. Немного неудобно возиться постоянно удалением и добавлением аттрибута, но зато спокойно можно писать на современном синтаксисе React

### Пример кода, с поддержкой современного синтаксиса React в HTML секции

```html
<div id="react"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
const {useState} = React;
const {createRoot} = ReactDOM;

// Пример функционального компонента
const Counter = ({initialValue}) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialValue);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`(Render) initialValue was ${initialValue}`);
  })
  
  React.useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1')
      
      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        
        console.log(data);
      } else {
        console.log("Can't get data");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }, [])

  return <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>You clicked me {count} time(s)</button>
}

// Пример классового компонента
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Counter initialValue={0} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

// Рендеринг
const rootContainer = document.querySelector('#react');

if (rootContainer === null) throw new Error('There is no root container');

const root = createRoot(rootContainer);

root.render(<App />);
</script>
```