# Инструкция по вставке воспроизводимого примера

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Я раньше думал, что перейдя по ссылке [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) новичкам показывается как вставить воспроизводимый пример (Фрагмент кода), но там только определения того что такое минимальность, самодостаточность и воспроизводимость

Предлагаю в секцию "Воспроизводимость" или под каким-то новым заголовком, например "Как добавить фрагмент кода для вопросов по JS/HTML/CSS", показать как можно вставить Фрагмент кода

Просто уже не один десяток раз, я пишу инструкцию новичкам как можно тут вставлять фрагмент кода, чтобы мы могли запускать и видеть результаты. И они удивляются что тут так можно было оказывается. Я уже писал один раз [инструкцию как вставить код React](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12004/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%a4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-stack-snippet-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-react-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-jsx). Если вам идея понравится, то могу подготовить более общую статью по тому как вообще пользоваться Фрагментом кода. Ниже можно будет открыть список, который может дополнить любой желающий про расширенные возможности Фрагмента кода, куда например можно будет вставить ссылку на инструкцию по React

##### UPD

Появилась ещё одна идея как это можно реализовать. Чтобы сильно не менять содержимое странички, предлагаю в конце странички до последнего абзаца вставить абзац с примерно таким текстом ("[Фрагмент кода]" будет ссылкой на вопрос на мете, о Фрагменте кода):

> Для воспросов, касающихся:
>
> - `JS`
> - `HTML`
> - `CSS`
>
> можно использовать [Фрагмент кода], чтобы вставить минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый, прямо на сайте, код. Это поможет участникам сразу запустить ваш код, увидеть рузультат/проблему и немедленно приступить к помощи

Мне эта идея больше нравится, потому что при желании, каждый участник в будущем сможет внести свою пользу в данный вопрос, в том смысле что, править вопрос на мете намного легче и быстрее, чем предлагать правки на страницах справки и ждать их одобрения

Comment: Наверное логично добавить, хотя, по идее та страница для всех языков.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я тоже так думаю, потому я больше за открытие новой секции с указанием для вопросов по каким языкам эта секция предназначена, чем изменение содержимого секции "Воспроизводимость"

Comment: @Qwertiy Хотя я сейчас подумал, чем открывать новую секцию или сильно менять содержимое можно добавить 1 предложение-ссылку, которая будет вести на мету, где будет вопрос про Фрагмент кода в общем. Так можно будет в случае чего как раз поправлять содержимое вопроса, без лишней волокиты