# Копирование готового решения в ответ

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

Ни для кого не новость, что на многие (если не на все) [вопросы новичков](http://pikabu.ru/story/blagodarnost_3998612) можно нагулить готовое решение за несколько секунд, просто составив правильный поисковый запрос на английском.

Собственно, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/494339/197447). `java print month calendar` - первые две строчки выдачи. Ссылки на источник в ответе нет. При этом кусок кода я бы не назвал очевидным, комментарии не переведены.

Насколько такие решения соответствуют политике ресурса? С одной стороны, тогда на каждый второй такой вопрос можно отвечать "Я думаю это то, что вам нужно" (c) и, бац - копипастить готовое решение. С другой, тут вроде как собирается база знаний, а ответ хороший.

Ссылки-ответы и ссылки-комментарии удаляются, но и готовое (неочевидное) решение без указания первоистоника тоже немного коробит.

Прошу прощения, если эта тема уже поднималась.

Comment: Если первоисточником является ответ на StackExchange, то действует [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), требующая указания ссылки. То, что автор её нарушил, как минимум некрасиво.

Comment: Ответ с кодом без объяснений имеет некоторую ценность. Ценность ответа, в котором код объяснён, гораздо выше.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Нет, я как раз постеснялся постить, даже с указанием источника. Подумал, может кто от себя захочет попробовать написать. Оказалось тратить личное время на то, что мгновенно гуглится дураков нет. :)

Comment: @enzo Я не знаю какова политика сайта и прочее......но мое вот мнение: если бы кто-то взял бы мое  (в свободном доступе) решение и применил его где-то или поделился с кем-то, кому оно помогло - уже хорошо. И не важно указали ли источником меня или нет....это всё идет просто для помощи остальным.......это ж не программу мою стырили и продают налево направо........ с владом только соглашусь - что прокоменитровать код чуть  и пояснить слега было бы неплохо

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский С моей точки зрения, тут не вопрос этики. Не думаю что кто-то там реально переживает за свой или чужой код в открытом доступе. Он для того и выкладывается, чтобы обогатить сообщество. Давать линк на источник - не более чем хороший тон и дань чужому труду. Смысл в том, что система и сами пользователи должны как-то стимулировать качественные самостоятельные решения - их приятно читать, на них учишься. Ну а иначе останется соревноваться, кто быстрее нагуглит готовый сниппет. Перефразируя исходный вопрос,- "А чо, так можно было?". Ответ, в общем, понятен.

Answer (score 6):

А почему, собственно, нет? Человеку нужен ответ, а не ваше стеснение и моральные терзания. Сайту нужны ответы, а не ссылки в комментариях. Что лучше, скопированный ответ или отсутствие оного? По моему, ответ очевиден.

Да, много вопросов выливается в «кто быстрее нагуглит». Ну и что? Главное, чтобы ответ был, а как он получен — не важно.

Что касается качества копирования: конечно, если код требует объяснения, то лучше его объяснить. Но, повторюсь, лучше не очень качественный ответ, чем вообще отсутствие ответа.

Answer (score 4):

Одна из проблем «стандартных формув» в отсутствии возможности найти нужную информацию быстро. Согласитесь, попадая на тему про очередь сообщений в Windows из поисковика, вы вряд ли хотите улучшить ваши навыки в сатире, вы вряд ли хотите узнать о политических взглядах коллег. Ваш интерес – очередь сообщений в Windows. Не более. Модель Stack Overflow дает возможность избежать вредоносного шума.

Существует огромное количество информации на старых «информационных свалках». Отфильтровать и воссоздать все эти знания небольшой группой людей не представляется возможным. Это возможно только если мы вместе, всем сообществом разработчиков, будем заниматься созданием нашей общей базы знаний.

Наша база знаний состоит из конкретных прикладных решений. Решения – это ответы. Ответы даются на вопросы. Без вопросов мы с вами просто не сможем понять, что именно все еще ценно, а чему и дальше быть на «свалке информации». Таким образом, простой вопрос, ответ на который знаток может быстро найти, является ключом к знаниям, который также показывает, что знания все еще нужны сообществу.

Здорово, когда публикуя найденный ответ, знатоки добавляют своей личной экспертизы к решению (именно благодаря личному опыту в ответах, Stack Overflow имеет такую популярность среди наших коллег). С другой стороны, знатоки помогают коллегам по своей доброй воле. Вряд ли они хотят навредить или обидеть кого–то, не публикуя обратную ссылку на источник. Скорее всего, просто еще не все участники успели перенять принятую модель публикации ответов. Чтобы подсказать автору, что ответ имеет недостатки, пожалуйста, используйте [шаблонные комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1222/).