# Что вы пишете, когда предлагаете автору вопроса принять ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, принятые-ответы

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, что вы пишете в комментариях, когда предлагаете автору вопроса определиться с принятием ответа — вашего или чужого.

Время от времени новички эмоционально благодарят в комментариях, но не замечают галку рядом с ответом. А однажды пришлось объяснять, что право принимать ответы отличается от права голосовать и даётся сразу же.

Или заглядываешь в незакрытый вопрос и видишь, что хороший ответ уже есть. И тогда хотелось бы, чтобы автор отметил его как принятый или объяснил бы, чем он не устраивает.

На Мете есть [список шаблонных комментариев](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1222/). Но, думаю, полезно увидеть варианты друг друга, чтобы каждый мог отточить свою формулировку или создать новую.

Comment: Просто даю ссылку в комментарии к вопросу на [соответствующий раздел справки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) с таким же, как в справке заголовок, сообщением.

Comment: @pavlofff В таком случае проверьте, пожалуйста, станет ли справка лучше [от этих изменений](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3397/). Что надо учесть?

Answer (score 17):

Предпочитаю даже не писать, а голосовать за вопрос автора, особенно, если автор вопроса новичок с незначительным количеством кармы. Мне кажется появляющиеся зелененькие циферки в верхней части экрана привлекают внимание куда больше, побуждают исследовать вопрос принятия ответа и голосования более подробно.

В конце концов, это просто приятно, что вопрос был оценен положительно и к нему проявили внимание. Это настраивает посетителя на дружелюбный и позитивный тон, побуждает голосовать и вообще внимательно относиться к сайту и остальным посетителям.

Когда у новичка нет кармы, ему нечего терять, поэтому минусы он воспринимает негативно, но они не побуждают его разбираться почему минусуют или корректировать поведение. Он не заинтересован в развитии сообщества, он решает свои собственные проблемы, а сообщество воспринимает как барьер на пути к их решению. Когда у посетителя появляется карма, он начинает ей невольно дорожить, особенно, если она открывает ему доступ к инструментам, которыми он пользуется.

Поэтому самое правильное мне кажется не добиться от посетителя зеленой галки, а задержат его на сайте, интегрировать в сообщество. Если ему будет интересно, из-за ответов, из-за дружелюбного обсуждения, из-за кармы - он разберется и уделит внимание всем аспектам сайта, в том числе и принятию ответов. А ускорить этот процесс мне кажется, можно только голосуя за вопросы. Получив ответ, посетитель может больше никогда не вернуться на сайт, чтобы почитать комментарий. После получения голосов, вероятность, что он задержится гораздо выше.

Comment: Совет хорош ещё и тем, что таким же способом можно поддержать авторов ответов. У меня впечатление, что у многих первый ответ оказывается ответом на вопрос новичка. Из-за этого человек рискует недополучить внимание со стороны автора вопроса, а плюс от более опытного участника поддержит на первых шагах.

Answer (score 10):

Обычно у новичков хватает мозгов хотя бы поставить плюсик. В этом случае система выводит сообщение, что ответ можно и принять. Соответственно, в подавляющем большинстве случаев никаких действий не требуется. Кажется, ещё были напоминалки, если зайти на сайт через какое-то время, а ответ так и не принят. В общем, не заморачивайтесь, непринятые ответы — это статистическая погрешность.

Если ну очень хочется дать совет новичку, то можно оставить любой комментарий. Формальный шаблонный комментарий без смайлика — по-моему, не лучший способ общения с новичком, который сказал "спасибо", поэтому я всегда пишу такой комментарий вручную и снабжаю смайликом, если уж так зудит дать совет.

Одно прошу: когда ответ принят или комментарий проигнорирован достаточно долго, не забывайте подчистить за собой мусор. Обсуждение галочек и плюсиков в комментариях засоряет страницу.

Comment: Плюсик можно поставить [после 15 баллов репутации](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). А чтобы их собрать, нужны плюсики :)

Comment: Надо же... Никогда не знал. Похоже, таким образом много людей выпадает из потенциальных поставщиков баллов. Кое у кого может возникнуть вопрос -- "стоит ли им вообще отвечать?". Очевидно, лишь незнание таких правил спасает ситуацию.

Comment: @avp Получается, что два ответа дополняют друг друга: [cheops советует](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3400/208926) голосовать за вопросы новичков, эти голоса помогают начать голосовать самим и после этого включаются "дополнительные ускорители" (подсказки, знаки за голоса....)