# Нормально ли просить в комментариях принять ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии, принятые-ответы

После прошлых обсуждений ([Стоит ли напоминать о принятии ответа?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7910/15479) и т.п.) что-то поменялось или я плох в английском, или на MSE какую-то дичь пытаются втирать?

Под ответом: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319361/260198 высокорепные участники утверждают, что просить принять ответ запрещено:

> It's literally on the blacklist of words along with swear words
>   because of how often these inappropriate comments are posted and how
>   infrequently they're appropriate. It's absolutely appropriate to flag
>   a comment like that.

Я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: На мой взгляд - дичь. [Ответил там](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/319380/309650) - посмотрим, как отреагируют.

Comment: Может в их обществе попрошайничество совсем неприличное занятие?

Comment: @avp я бы не назвал это попрошайничеством.

Comment: Из приведенной цитаты следует именно это (только весьма завуалировано (бинайс же -))

Comment: Тоже [отписался в комментариях](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319359/etiquette-of-accepting-answers/319380#comment1046545_319361)

Comment: @avp кстати, в Америке попрошайкам (и не только) запрещено голосом просить, поэтому они трясут банками с мелочью. Всякие пляжные продавцы щебечут, а уличные промоутеры щёлкают визитками. Короче, изгаляются как могут. Может и к комментам потому просящим отношение такое. Надо символ специальный заюзать какой-нибудь :)

Answer (score 5):

Отношение англоязычного ресурса к таким комментариям всегда было неоднозначным.

В 2009-м [человек пишет](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat?noredirect=1&lq=1), что такие комментарии кажутся ему попрошайничеством. @BillTheLizard отвечает, что их можно оставлять, если нужно показать новому участнику, что ответы можно принимать:

> I think that's acceptable. If you were encouraging them to accept an incomplete or unhelpful answer, that would be rep-whoring. Encouraging them to accept a good answer (even your own) is just teaching them the right way to use the system.

В ответе на [вопрос из 2012 года](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140256/is-it-ok-to-tell-the-op-to-accept-an-upvoted-answer?noredirect=1&lq=1) @RobertHarvey явно указывает, что такие комментарии допустимы только если вопрос задал новичок:

> Accepting answers is an entirely optional activity. Consequently, asking users to accept your answer feels like rep whoring to me.
>
> If the OP has a 0% accept rate, you can link them here: How does accepting an answer work?

В [2013 году @Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199007/should-you-ask-a-question-asker-to-accept-an-answer?noredirect=1&lq=1) высказался жестче:

> The community consensus is to leave it alone.
>
> Don't ask for people to accept - it isn't as important as that. It is an indicator by the question asker that the specific answer was the one most helpful to them.
>
> **Some people only ever come on to ask questions, get an answer and then they go away, till the next question. This is OK.**
>
> The community indicator for a good answer is upvotes.

В общем и целом, на Stack Overflow по-английски подобного рода комментарии всегда расценивались, в лучшем случае, как не относящийся к делу шум, в худшем же, как пассивная агрессия. Допустимыми они считались только в отдельных случаях (когда автор новичок и есть большая уверенность что его проблема решена). Как видно из комментариев многие пользователи/модераторы считают что даже в таких случаях просить «галочку» не стоит, дабы не создавать лишнего шума.

Вообще, по сравнению с нами, на большом Stack Overflow крайне низкая терпимость к шуму и всё, что не относится напрямую к вопросам и ответам (приветствия, слова благодарности, добрые пожелания, просьбы и т.п.) удаляется без раздумий. У нас тут трафика меньше и люди снисходительнее относятся к элементам общения. В этом отношении английский сайт больше похож на энциклопедию, а наш — на форум.

Стоит также заметить, что даже у нас такие комменты однозначно считаются шумом и допустимы только если употребляются ограниченно. Любой такой коммент старше недели можно смело отметить как более не являющийся необходимым ([хорошим тоном будет удалить свой комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3399/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82#3402) если он не возымел эффекта). Навязчивые просьбы поставить галочку недопустимы.

Comment: Полагаю, что для новичков должна вылазить автоматическая шапка при переходе на страницу с их вопросом, если там появился новый отвт. Типа той, что говорит про использование cookie и прочего. Только с надписью - "отметьте вопрос если он правильный" или типа того. А в комментариях ни-ни.

Answer (score -1):

Нет, просить точно не стоит. Это давление на пользователя. Вообще, лучше избегать подобного. И даже не думать об этом. Новичок может не разобраться и отметить не тот ответ, просто, потому что почувствует себя обязанным. Либо, не захочет возвращаться, чтобы избавить себя от навязчивых просьб. Они могут не казаться навязчивыми лично Вам, но это ничего не меняет. Это портит атмосферу.

Лучше для новичков показывать ненавязчивое сообщение в шапке, как делает, например askubuntu.com:

[image: don't forget to vote]

Но только для новичков. Примерный перевод прилагается.

> *Добро пожаловать. Если Вы нашли этот вопрос полезным, не забудьте проголосовать за вопрос и ответ тоже.*

---

P.S.: этот ответ не про баннер, если что. Баннер просто как альтернатива, невозможность либо неприемлемость которой, ничего не меняет.

Comment: Такой баннер - это не особенность askubuntu, он есть на всех сайтах SE. И я не могу сказать, что он менее навязчив, чем совет в комментарии. Скорее всего даже наоборот, он более навязчив, так как висит в шапке, блокирует некоторые контролы и будет появляться вновь и вновь при определённых условиях. Собственно, обратите внимание на [соответствующий вопрос на MSE по этому баннеру](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91553/339911).

Comment: @älёxölüt, просто там он появляется всегда, а не как предложено.

Comment: @älёxölüt, на SO и здесь я его не разу не видел. Только на askubuntu, и на serferfault (или как-то так). Наверное выпилили. Но на SO у меня репутация больше 100, как и здесь, а вот на остальных 100. Но я предлагаю его показывать только при заходе на собственный вопрос, если появился новый ответ. Можно ещё добавить ограничений. И дизайн переработать.

Comment: @IvanBlack "Можно ещё добавить ограничений", "и дизайн переработать". Забудьте.

Comment: Проголосовать (за любой) вопрос или ответ это не то же самое, что поставить галочку когда ответили на ваш вопрос!

Comment: Это не про баннер ответ, если что.