# Почему не ставят галочку за правильный ответ?

Tags: обсуждение

Уже неделю на Stack Overflow и вижу, что не ставят галочку за правильный ответ, почему?

Comment: галочку ставят авторы вопросов на те ответы, которые им помогли.....но, увы, галочку ставят не 100% задающих. Некоторые из них приходят, задают вопрос и уходят  даже не взглянув на ответ, кто-то забывает, кто-то задал вопрос с одного аккаунта, потом забыл пароль, завел другой, а значит галку уже не может поставить, причин множество. Так что всегда её ждать — нет смысла.

Comment: И давайте не забывать, что помимо типовых причин сейчас добавляется ещё одна: новогодние каникулы. Активность на сайте снижается, многие уехали и проводят выходные без интернета.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Галочка за ответ -- дело добровольное. Если автор вопроса считает, что ответ решил его проблему, мы *рекомендуем* поставить галочку. Но это полностью его решение, имеет право не ставить.

Не берите в голову, *хорошие* авторы вопросов галочку ставят всегда. Ну если нашёлся хороший ответ, да.

Comment: бывает что автор просто не в курсе про галочку :)

Comment: @Grundy: Ну и такое бывает. Как сделать лучше UI, чтобы авторы вопросов понимали, чего от них хотят? (Я не в курсе.)

Comment: @VladD Думаю, что [ответ alexolut](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4475/220571) может частично разрешить проблему.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: Поддерживаю. Скромное напоминание о том, что надо бы принять ответ, поможет тем новичкам, которые ещё не разобрались в принципах работы сайта.

Answer (score 17):

Дополнение к ответу VladD.

Вы можете комментарием к вопросу подсказать автору, что он мог бы воспользоваться принятием ответов, при необходимости. [На Мете есть вопрос со списком шаблонных комментариев](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1222/). В свою очередь, я использую следующий

> Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Кстати часто помогает. Часто ещё прошу "проголосовать за" подобным образом. Или изменить принятый ответ.

Answer (score 2):

А мне сейчас дали ответы, а две галочки поставить нельзя... Это не менее обидно чем вообще не ставят...

Comment: Это хорошая тема для нового вопроса — как выбрать, кому поставить галочку.