# Как использовать шаблонные комментарии?

Tags: поддержка, faq, шаблонные-комментарии

[В старом движке Хэшкода были шаблонные комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13/181472). Похоже, что и сейчас некоторые участники их используют. Есть вопрос «[Список шаблонных комментариев](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1222/181472)», в котором обсуждаются формулировки новых комментариев, актуальных для StackOverflow.

Можно ли автоматизировать использование этих комментариев? Как это сделать?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Один из вариантов — greasemonkey-скрипт AutoReviewComments - [Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).

## Возможности

При создании комментария появляется вот такая кнопка `auto`:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии предлагается список из различных комментариев. Этот список — полностью настраиваемый для каждого сайта в отдельности.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Установка.

- [Расширение для Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoreviewcomments/bcfoamnigomkoaaiceppbbdlembpeejc)
- [Расширение для Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/se-autoreviewcomments/)
- [Как пользовательский скрипт](https://raw.github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments/master/dist/autoreviewcomments.user.js). ( [Как включить пользовательские скрипты.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info))

#### Конфигурация

Нажмите `import/export`, чтобы редактировать сохраненные шаблоны.

- [Готовые шаблоны](https://gist.github.com/AlKach/ac95178fe5a0cd5d7206), [предложенные участником fori1ton](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5?lq=1#comment72_30)
- [Мой собственный набор шаблонов](https://gist.github.com/NickVolynkin/bc62b4d4615635e597ae), собранный на основе набора fori1ton.

---

2021-01-19: greasemonkey-скрипт AutoReviewComments требует [патча](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1233306/178576) (css изменился в диалоге закрытия):

```
--- autoreviewcomments.user.js.orig 2021-01-14 14:36:47.989240459 +0000
+++ autoreviewcomments.user.js  2021-01-19 08:26:01.918776847 +0000
@@ -828,7 +828,7 @@
     }
     attachAutoLinkInjector(".js-add-link", findCommentElements, injectAutoLink, autoLinkAction);
     attachAutoLinkInjector(".edit-post", findEditSummaryElements, injectAutoLinkEdit, autoLinkAction);
-    attachAutoLinkInjector(".close-question-link", findClosureElements, injectAutoLinkClosure, autoLinkAction);
+    attachAutoLinkInjector(".js-close-question-link", findClosureElements, injectAutoLinkClosure, autoLinkAction);
     attachAutoLinkInjector(".review-actions input:first", findReviewQueueElements, injectAutoLinkReviewQueue, autoLinkAction);
 
     /**
@@ -862,7 +862,7 @@
      *                     comment should be placed.
      */
     function findClosureElements(where) {
-      var injectNextTo = $(".close-as-off-topic-pane textarea");
+      var injectNextTo = $("#site-specific-comment textarea");
       var placeCommentIn = injectNextTo;
       return [injectNextTo, placeCommentIn];
     }
```