# Обучение новых участников правилам сообщества

Tags: поддержка, faq

Stack Overflow полностью управляется сообществом. Сообщество – это реальные люди: каждый день к нам присоединяется порядка девяноста новых участников, далеко не все из которых полностью понимают модель работы сайта. От того, каким будет их первый опыт на сайте, очень зависит то, как в будущем будет выглядеть наша база знаний.

Многие сильные участники уже давно подключились к обучению вновь присоединившихся коллег правилам использования сайта. В основном это выражается в рекомендациях правильных действий в определенных ситуациях с помощью [комментариев](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1222/). Именно через комментарии мы можем объяснить базовые принципы и, возможно, привлечь внимание к разделам справки, которую, возможно, читали даже не все опытные участники сообщества.

#### Когда стоит использовать шаблонные комментарии?

Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь использовать шаблонные комментарии (опубликованные другими участниками или ваши личные) во благо развития нашей общей базы знаний:

1. *В очередях проверок.* Особенно в очереди первых сообщений. Например, иногда полезно подсказывать, что за ответы можно не только голосовать, но и отмечать их верными.
2. *В любом месте, где вы видите, что участник не до конца понимает, как использовать сайт верно.* Бывает, например, что участники используют ответы вместо дополнения вопроса. С большой вероятностью ваша рекомендация в виде комментария поможет им понять работу движка.

#### Автоматизация добавления шаблонных комментариев

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на прекрасную публикацию на Мете от [@Nick Volynkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin) – «[Как использовать шаблонные комментарии?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1225/)», в которой рассказывается про [скрипт, автоматизирующий работу с комментариями](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/). Расширение поможет вам всегда иметь набор шаблонных комментариев под рукой.

#### Уменьшение информационного шума

Мета-комментарии несут огромную пользу для автора вопроса или ответа, но вносят ненужный информационный шум в базу знаний. Если вы попали в тему, где к вопросу или ответу дан мета-комментарий, который к текущему моменту стал неактуальным, пожалуйста, удалите его!

Мета-комментарии становятся неактуальными, если участник, которому адресован комментарий, просмотрел его либо никогда не посмотрит. Можно формализовать это в следующем правиле:

- участник отреагировал на комментарий правкой или ответным комментарием;
- согласно статистике в учетной записи участника, он был на сайте после размещения комментария.
- мета-комментарию более 48 часов.

Если одно из этих условий выполняется, смело удаляйте все неотносящееся к теме вопроса! Если у вас недостаточно репутации для удаления комментария, отметьте его сигналом тревоги.

Также спешу предложить обратить внимание на [расширение для автоматического удаления своих комментариев](https://stackapps.com/questions/6316/).

Stack Overflow – это инструмент, который надо уметь использовать по назначению. Чем раньше новые участники понимают, как правильно использовать сайт, тем эффективней их участие в сообществе.

Comment: "Пожалуйста, удалите его" - не все же здесь модераторы. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin В этом случае, хорошо бы отмечать такие комментарии сигналом тревоги.