# Нужен ли нам «фриланс» на Stack Overflow?

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии

Мы с вами обсуждали вопрос комментариев уже не раз и хорошо знаем, [какие комментарии неуместны на Stack Overflow и почему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2349/). Существует особый случай, который хочется рассмотреть отдельно. Некоторое время назад начал вырисовываться небольшой тренд — стали появляться комментарии с упоминанием слова «фриланс». Например:

- > Это не фриланс.
- > Здесь не биржа фриланса.
- > С такими "вопросами" надо на фриланс обращаться.
- > А на фриланс обратиться не хотите?

… и далее по списку. Такие комментарии публикуются буквально несколькими участниками. Предполагая, что «фриланс» может оказаться заразным и превратиться в эпидемию, предлагаю сообществу рассмотреть вопрос, когда подобное поведение допустимо, а когда — нет.

Мне бы очень хотелось услышать ваши мысли по этому вопросу. Могут ли подобные фриланс–комментарии помочь нам улучшить русскоязычное сообщество и нашу базу знаний? Если у вас есть интересный взгляд на проблему, пожалуйста, опубликуйте его в ответе к этому вопросу.

Comment: добавь слово фриланс а автоудалятор комментариев :)

Comment: Ещё про один «тренд» бы написали — [**телепатов в отпуске**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B+%D0%B2+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5+site:ru.stackoverflow.com&newwindow=1). По моему мнению, подобные комментарии [**нарушают п. 4**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2349/199934). Спасибо.

Comment: Примеры вопросов приведите, а то беспредметный разговор.

Comment: дружеский совет "валить на фриланс" гораздо человечнее безличных минуса за вопрос и голоса за закрытие

Comment: Думаю, проще удалять такие комменты и уведомлять таких пользователей, что они перепутали ресурс, здесь люди добровольно помогают друг-другу при желании и знании, либо просто наводящими подсказками, либо ответами на вопрос с решением или просто промолчать. По этому лучше промолчать, нежели отсылать пользователей решать вопросы за деньги. По этому соглашусь с `Grundy`.

Comment: @Igor если вы бесплатно не хотите делиться знаниями, то имеете на это полное право, но Stack Overflow не для вас¶ Назначение комментариев улучшить вопрос, помочь написать ответ, помочь будущим посетителям с похожей проблемой. Если не понимаете зачем вопросы закрывать или чем полезны голоса за вопрос, можете на Мете вопрос задать или существующие ответы поискать.

Comment: @jfs Проецируем понемногу? Нельзя ли обменять часть репутации на доллары?

Comment: @And чем упоминание фриланса или гугла не подсказка?

Comment: @jfs лихо вы обобщили.

Comment: Обычно такие комментарии появляются под вопросами вида "Знать не знаю %названия технологии%, но надо сделать %весьма общее описание объёмной задачи%". По-хорошему, надо просто закрывать такие вопросы. Всё равно никто не напишет в ответе инструкцию по разработке социальной сети на Java, тем более достаточно подробную для тех, кто не способен написать даже _Hello World_.

Comment: Может вообще комментирование для всех запретить(сделать доступным только от 1к репутации). Спасибо - нельзя, фриланс - нельзя, про гугл - тоже нельзя. Какой _реальный_ вред от этих комментариев? ТС, который и вопрос-то внятно сформулировать не может получит психологическую травму? Ну это не серьезно.

Comment: @Suvitruf, Кто сказал, что это не подсказка? - Это не уместная подсказка. Такие подсказки могут отогнать пользователей на другой ресурс, чего в принципе допускать нельзя. Они пришли за помощью именно суда, скорее всего гугл им дал знать, что вам тут помогут, а вы сразу же выгоняете их на фриланс или снова искать другие места, но только не тут.

Comment: @GreenDragon, если вам не нравится оформление вопроса, вы можете переформулировать вопрос ТС или дать такую возможность модератору - отправив жалобу на данный вопрос. - Вы можете потребовать от пользователя более развернутую информацию и код, если он есть у пользователя.

Comment: @And, требовать тоже нельзя. Переформулировать до 2к - могут на ревью правку забраковать как меняющую суть так что это пустая трата времени. Но суть не в этом. Проблема в том, что это работает в одну сторону - если опытный участник приведет вопрос в адекватный вид, халявщик наштампует еще множество. Если 1 раз ясно дать понять что SO место для тех кто что-то может сам, а для всех остальных есть фриланс, то это будет намного полезнее. Лично я ни разу никого во фриланс не отправлял т.к. более чем уверен что большинство ТС знают о такой возможности сами. Но запрещать это делать - неправильно.

Comment: @GreenDragon, тогда смысла от этого ресурса не будет, если тут будут только те, кто что-то может, а те, кто не могут ничего или совсем чучуть, что не меняет суть и все равно склоняется к ничего, то уйдут большинство на более менее адекватный ресурс. Но ведь изначально, суть ресурса давать знания и делиться ими бесплатно, будь это немощь, будь это опытный - хоть кто. Он пришел за помощью, он хочет разобраться, не знает он - как искать и не понимает - как правильно оформить тот или иной вопрос, а вы ему тебе тут не место иди на фриланс.

Comment: @And , наоборот, тогда ресурс будет намного лучше. SO - база знаний, знаний, а не примеров некачественных вопросов. Помочь тому кто хочет разобраться - правильно, сделать за другого его работу - зависит от контекста. Проблема ратующих за запрет в том, что пока нет ни одного примера где отправка во фриланс не только была бы неуместной, но и шла в разрез с духом и буквой правил сообщества.

Comment: @GreenDragon Обновил ответ. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @GreenDragon дело в том, что "не может и не хочет делать сам" это, чаще всего, чистое предположение. Оценка "халявщик" - тоже. Примеры есть в [ответе Николаса ниже](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7175/). Если сделать [выборку из SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/edit/845691), то видно, что иногда совет "на фриланс" действительно полезен (т.к. топикастер ищет именно исполнителя, а не пытается найти решение). А иногда - на фриланс посылают совершенно мимо.

Answer (score 33):

Вот тут пишут, что человек постарался, описал свою проблему, преодолел какие-то свои психологические барьеры чтобы публично задать интересующий его вопрос и такие комментарии его отпугнут.

Если человек действительно старался и просто допустил какие-то ошибки при оформлении своего вопроса, то это видно невооруженным глазом и я очень сильно сомневаюсь, что под таким вопросом возникнут комментарии вида отсылки на фриланс-биржу, в комментариях будут рекомендации по исправлению, а в худшем случае на вопрос посыпятся минусы и/или тревоги, что, кстати нового пользователя тоже может отпугнуть.

На деле же такие комментарии сыпятся под вопросы людей которые либо не удосужились прочитать правила, либо пролистали их и плевать хотели на их соблюдение. Эти люди абсолютно не ценят ни затраченное время на прочтенный вопрос (как правило, еще и оформленный жутким образом), ни теоретически затраченное время на составление ответа, хороший исход если они поставят плюс под ответом и его примут, а то можно и этого не дождаться. Люди просто хотят на халяву делегировать любому эксперту решение своей задачи, возможно довольно-таки нетривиальной или же просто неинтересной и объемной. Эти люди не хотят делать вклад в базу знаний, не хотят ничему научиться, они хотят чтобы их проблему решили.

Для таких индивидов я не считаю отправление на фриланс-биржу недружелюбным, это действительно тот тип ресурсов, на который автору вопроса нужно идти и на которой он либо не идет из-за того, что не знает о наличии таковых, либо просто не хочет платить, не хочет справлять сам, а результат получить хочется.

Comment: Вот тут пожалуй я соглашусь, хотя все ответы хороши, но вы описали ситуацию с которой явно не поспоришь. Редактируя вопросы, просматривая новые входящие я очень часто наблюдаю как-раз таки вот такую, ситуацию. Я добавляю в комментарии просьбы ознакомится со справкой, уже даже со стрелками что за чем, но лишь единицы читают и делают какие-то поправки. Чем такие вопросы ценны? Я не знаю..

Comment: Но бываю ситуации, конечно, как коллеги описали выше, что человек не успевает элементарно отреагировать и внести ясность в то, почему именно его вопрос ценен и тут биржа не поможет..., а ему около 5-6 минусов слету и пожелание идти куда подальше, а собственно на фриланс

Comment: попробуйте прочитать уже опубликованные ответы, там уже явно описано, почему "отправление на фриланс" недружелюбно (ответ в очередной раз подтверждает правило: люди, которые других обвиняют в лени, сами её демонстрируют).

Comment: @jfs есть аспекты из-за которых в реальных условиях эта позиция мне кажется неубедительной, почему - расписал в ответе, ваше право придерживаться другого мнения. Замечание не считаю конструктивным.

Comment: @yolosora вы имеете право на своё мнение, но не свои факты

Comment: @jfs Реальных фактов пока не видно ни у одной из сторон.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: что вы под "реальными" фактами подразумеваете. И сколько денег готовы поставить, что нет ни одного факта на этой странице (очевидная ложь)

Comment: @jfs Я не держу пари со случайными незнакомцами из интернета (понятия не имею, к чему вы мне это пишете). Факт на данной странице только один - "на SO стали появляться комментарии с определенным словом". Нет ни одного примера вопроса, под которым он появлялся, нет статистики среднего рейтинга таких вопросов, количество тревог на комментариях и т.п. Соответственно, никакого практического смысла это все не имеет.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight да они тут уже столько понаобсуждали, но я так и не увидел примеров вопросов, которым такой комментарий нанёс вред. Словоблудие ради словоблудия.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/818789

Comment: @Igor не вы должны вопросы такие искать, а те, кто считает, что в каких-то вопросах рекомендация идти на фриланс навредила вопросу (:

Comment: Обновил ответ. Я не согласен, что подобное необходимо даже в случае плохих вопросов: уровень агрессии в сообществе будет расти, «случайно» мы будем отшивать хороших участников, а тому, кто паразитирует поифк, его задача не знания, выполненная работа. Простым закрытием вопроса мы не даем нарушителю получить решение и не навредим сообществу, а если автор поймет свою ошибку в вопросе и сможет ее исправить, уверен, он сможет очень успешно сосуществовать в нашем прекрасном дружном коллективе!

Comment: Некоторое время назад в вопросах по `sql` появлялись вопросы от пользователя, который явно не желал разбираться в том, что такое `sql`. За несколько месяцев никакого прогресса в знаниях. Он просто копипастил ответы на старый вопрос и задавал новый. По моему в таких случаях отправлять  на фриланс самое оно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да мотивация при инициативе понятна, просто кажется, что в реальных условиях она не так хороша, как кажется в голове. Почему считаете, что уровень агрессии в сообществе будет расти? Есть ощущение, что он УЖЕ вырос по сравнению с прошлым?

Answer (score 12):

Беспредметный разговор. Ни примеров вопросов, ни примеров таких комментариев. Ну что, будем тогда абстрактно рассуждать.

1. SO - не биржа фриланса. Если человек ничего сам не сделал по задаче, а просит всё сделать за него, то такой вопрос нужно удалять/закрывать. Если кто-то потратит кучу времени на ответ, то автору это окажет лишь медвежью услугу. Свидетелей секты "SO - это не об одном человеке, это база знаний. Ответ на такой вопрос может помочь другим" прошу проходить мимо. Такие ответы помогут лишь таким же лентяям и лоботрясам.
2. SO - это не соц. сеть для детсадовцев. Не нужно с пользователями сюсюкаться, как с детишками. Посылать куда подальше, безусловно, не стоит, но и тратить время на человека, который чужой труд не ценит, нет смысла.
3. Вообще не понимаю проблемы. Такие комментарии я встречал только под вопросами, которые не несли никакой пользы сообществу. Если автор вопроса хоть какие-то попытки решить задачу предпринимал, а не просто просит сделать всё за него, то это сразу видно. Под такими вопросами нету комментариев из сабжа.

В общем, раз уж мы говорим максимально абстрактно, то в целом проблема высосана из пальца.

Comment: Ваш ответ хорош, но без агрессивных обобщений про "свидетелей секты", "детсадовцев" был бы лучше.

Comment: @GreenDragon возможно. Но я такой, какой я есть. Не люблю скрываться за красивыми словами.

Comment: Соглашусь с автором ответа. Проблема не в комментаторах, а в формулировке таких вопросов. Если вопрос сформулирован некорректно, он в любом случае будет закрыт/удален, а значит "фриланс"-комментарии вреда не приносят.

Comment: @RTK Как я писал в ответ, комментарии вредят не случайно зашедшим к нам людям, а постоянным участникам сообщества. Если вопрос плохой, надо его закрыть, объяснить, в чем проблемы. Подскажите, для чего шутки–ради публиковать подобный комментарий?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky никаких шуток. Вопрос закрывается, комментарий говорит автору, что это не фриланс биржа. Все довольны.

Comment: @Suvitruf Комментарий вида «А на фриланс обратиться не хотите?» ничего не говорит, он высмеивает и частно не по делю. Я привел в ответе примеры вопросов. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Видя ваш ответ, мне сразу всплывет в голове «[ярлык](http://anekdotov.net/anekdot/all/vtrmstptmchtmdk.htm)» русскоязычного сообщества. Хоть он в целом и не оправдывает себя, но мне кажется, ноги могут расти из подобной «прямоты», которая для кого–то выражения себя, но для другой стороны частенько выглядит оскорблением.

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, как вы считаете, объективны ли суждения про «детсад» и «секту»? Что если кто–то также думает о вас, и хотя вы с этим не согласны, он публично это все высказывает? Не кажется ли вам, что если снизить «градус» и сесть за стол переговоров, окажется, что за «сектой» скрывается простое недопонимание?

Comment: Подведя итог. Если откинуть «суровые выражения» и принять вашу позицию, какие бы условия для закрытия вопросов как «не фриланс» вы бы рекомендовали? Какова бы была формулировка причины закрытия на ваш взгляд?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky сектой я их называю потому что во всех обсуждениях они пытаются навязать свою точку зрения, не понимаю зачем.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky как правило все вопросы с комментариям про фриланс можно закрыть как "домашнюю работу".

Answer (score 10):

Обращаю внимание голосующих, что упоминание фриланса идёт ещё из [шаблонных комментариев времён Хэшкода](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1225/208074):

> ###[Q] Фриланс
>
> $SITENAME$ — это не фриланс-биржа. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос и уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.
>
> *Источник: [SO-comment-templates.txt, строка 25](https://gist.github.com/NickVolynkin/bc62b4d4615635e597ae#file-so-comment-templates-txt-L25)*

Учитывая, что весь список был составлен и опубликован модератором (Nick Volynkin), данная причина до недавнего времени не считалась чем-то плохим.

Comment: Я больше скажу, в справке (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) написано: "*Если для вас программирование — лишний предмет в учебной программе, есть сайты и люди на этих сайтах, выполняющие задания за материальное вознаграждение. Здесь предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот — моветон.*" - по сути, приправленный килограммом сахара посыл на фриланс-биржу

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Почему бы тогда этот параграф не использовать, подкорректировав чуть–чуть про работу за автора?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Ну, это не сильно поменяет суть. Если кто-то обижается на "Здесь не фриланс-биржа", они также могут обидеться на "Обратитесь на специализированный сайт, выполняющий задания за материальное вознаграждение", так как это то же самое.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Возможно, тогда стоит несколько переформулировать. Например, можно заложить что–то вроде пояснения, что на SO мы помогаем с конкретными техническими проблемами и если автор хочет получить решение, ему следует сделать то–то и то–то ("минимальный пример" и прочее). Затем дописать, что на этом сайте за деньги работу не делают, если это так необходимо. То есть на мой взгляд, нам следует (1) сказать что не так с вопросом, например, нет четкой технической проблемы; (2) как исправить. Вешать фриланс–клеймо на людей не верно. Я привел примеры вопросов с подобным комментарием в ответе

Answer (score 7):

> ### Коротко
>
> Пожалуйста, избегайте комментариев вида «вам к фрилансерам», «это не фриланс–биржа» и аналогичных. Проголосуйте против, за закрытие. Если вопрос не соответствует правилам сайта, но его можно исправить, дайте *информативный отзыв*, как это сделать.

На мой взгляд, любого рода комментарии—клише, где происходит посыл будь то к поисковику, фриланс бирже или чему–то другом, наносят вред сайту и сообществу.

1. *Такие комментарии необъективны, их можно добавить практически к любому вопросу.* Создание базы знаний сообщества держится на добродетели участников и понимании, что потраченные нами десятки минут выливаются в спасенные тысячи часов наших коллег (в том числе и нас самих). Некоторые вопросы, в которых я удалял подобные комментарии, получали впоследствии хорошие ответы. Фриланс — это всегда работа за автора, но [не любая работа за автора вне поля зрения Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4882/) (и [еще](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/)!)
2. *Такие комментарии неинформативны, они не говорят автору вопроса, что следует сделать, чтобы вопрос соответствовал правилам сайта.* Видя «сделайте» или «мне надо» вместо «как сделать» и «подскажите», пожалуйста, не отрабатывайте по *шаблону «типичного русскоязычного форума»*, точнее данному этому термину клише. Наш сайт — не типичный форум. В распоряжении участников большое количество инструментов модерации, которых нет на большинстве других сайтов. Если вопрос не соответствует, его надо закрыть, пояснив, что и как сделать автору, чтобы получить ответ на нашем сайте.

Если автор никогда ранее не использовал Stack Overflow для публикации вопросов или пользуется сайтом не так давно, ему может быть непонятна наша модель, неизвестны наши правила. Когда мы выдаем ему «фриланс–клише» вместо ответа или закрытия с поясняющим комментарием, он скорее всего разочаруется в нашем сообществе, так как, используя комментарии–отсылки, мы не особо далеко уходим «от того, что уже есть». Пожалуйста, избегайте комментариев вида «вам к фрилансерам», «это не фриланс–биржа» и аналогичных.

С другой стороны, старайтесь не впадать в крайности и помните про здравый смысл, «фриланс» «фрилансу» — рознь. «Послать» на «фриланс–биржу» можно и без слова «фриланс», и в то же время в самом слове «фриланс» нет ничего криминального, в некоторых контекстах оно более чем приемлемо.

**Обновление**

Немного цифр и графиков.

**Комментарии со словом «фриланс» во времени**

[image]

Давайте посмотрим, сколько людей (синяя линия) оставляет подобные комментарии:

[image]

Как выглядит распределение авторов таких комментариев? Ниже график количества сообщений к количеству участников, то есть сколько участников оставило N комментариев. Например, 260 человек оставило 1 подобный комментарий за все время сайта, 1 человек оставил более 40 подобных комментариев.

[image]

Таким образом, за все время жизни сайта всего 56 человек оставляли более 5 подобных комментариев. Или 19, если рассматривать комментарии оставленные с 2017. В 2018 году было 4 участника, с 5 и более комментариями. Оставили они 31 комментарий из 115 подобных комментариев в сумме.

**Еще немного фактов**

За все время было 803 комментария к вопросам со словом «фриланс». С 1–го января 2017 (то есть за последние почти полтора года) было опубликовано 397 таких комментариев к 343 вопросам. Авторами вопросов, получивших подобный комментарий, были 339 участников, 142 из них более никогда ничего не задавали на нашем сайте. 131 участник, «получивший фрилансом по лицу», имеет более 5 вопросов на сайте. Из 131 одного, пять участников, с наибольшим количеством вопросов имеют: 252 вопроса, 198 вопросов, 172 вопроса, 134 вопроса и 128 вопросов.

Только представьте, мы «отшили» 142 человека, еще 131 раз подобный комментарий написали тому, кто, вероятно, знал, как выглядит модель Stack Overflow, как минимум, человек, задавший 252 вопроса. Таким образом, на мой взгляд, в контексте первого случая, это вред сообществу, в контексте второго — просто бесполезно.

**Примеры вопросов**

Несколько случайных вопросов с подобными комментариями.

- [Преобразовать номер телефона к виду +7(000)000-00-00](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/808834/) (комментарий удален)
- [C# Вложенность при парсинге скобок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/659690/)
- [Получить количество входных параметров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732578/)
- [Сигн для etxt api на Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673595/)
- [Геометрическая фигура на HTML/CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811468/)
- [Кто может подсказать, как можно это сделать не используя картинку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673577/)

**Имеет ли значение, плохой ли вопрос?**

Если кто–то нарушает наши правила публикации вопросов, это не повод нам нарушать наши же правила дружелюбия! Подобной агрессией мы отталкиваем от себя потенциально хороших участников, подтверждая данный русскоязычному сообществу «[ярлык](http://anekdotov.net/anekdot/all/vtrmstptmchtmdk.htm)», который я много раз в личной опровергал, как минимум для Stack Overflow.

Пожалуйста, поймите, что любая агрессия совершенно не вредит «случайно попавшим на сайт людям», она вредит постоянным участникам, порождает злость и прения. Как только появляется вежливый отсыл к фрилансу, сразу возникает и более шутливый, затем надменный, а потом, стартует конкурс шутников: некоторые участники начинаю публиковать подобное везде, и не только про фриланс. Это как диета: не есть ничего много проще, чем есть чуть–чуть. Либо мы вместе принимаем новый ненасильственный формат профессионального обмена знаниями в Интернете, либо делаем «как все остальные», откатываясь на года назад в развитии сообщества. Подсказать про фриланс можно, и вполне корректных подробных комментариев достаточно на сайте. Но, пожалуйста, не путайте подсказку и посыл, не подменяйте прямоту неуважением. Это разные вещи.

Comment: Комментарий никак не мешает голосованию и закрытию.

Comment: @Qwertiy Подобные комментарии отталкивают людей от сообщества, пугают. Я не раз был свидетелем, когда к вопросу публиковали подобный комментарий в надменно шутливой форме, а вопрос в итоге получал и дополнение, и ответ от самого автора вопроса. То есть о каком–либо «фрилансе» речь не шла вообще. Человек использовал чуть «не верное» слово в вопросе и ему сразу ведро нечисти в лицо. Это не единичный случай. Чтобы не допустить таких «недопониманий», лучше вообще этот шаблонный «посыл» не использовать.

Comment: В данном ответе не сказано: // **1.** Что делать с уже существующими подобными комментариями. Если я поставлю тревогу к комментарию вроде `Здесь не биржа фриланса`, будет ли комментарий удалён модераторами? // **2.** Будут ли приниматься административные меры к участникам, многократно продолжающим допускать комментарии подобного рода? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных На мой взгляд, существующие комментариями нужно удалять! Если сообщество согласно с этим, вероятно, стоит обновить регулярное выражение для удаления комментариев без проверки модераторами, чтобы не перегружать очередь проверки тем, чего проверять особо не надо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Я лично не вижу причины для репрессий за один такой комментарий (и даже за два!) Это пережиток старых форумов, клише, которое досталось нам по наследству. Уверен, большинство участников вскоре привыкнут к профессиональному доброжелательному уважительному взаимодействию в интернете со временем. Часто участники видя, что подобные комментарии удаляются, быстро теряют интерес к их публикации. [На MSE прямо сейчас обсуждают](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309344/274323), можно ли прикрутить какую–либо автоматику для более динамичного отзыва системы, если участник нарушает правила.

Comment: Я не к тому, что это «пустяковое» нарушение (напротив, оно крайне серьезное), а к тому, что раньше «так делали все» везде, где нужно и нет. Считаю, что стоит относится с пониманием, шаг за шагом убеждать коллег, что фриланс–подход не ведет ни к чему положительному ни для автора вопроса, ни для автора комментария: сообщество разобщается, нет взаимопомощи, новых знаний не создается. От этого теряют все.

Comment: Почему комментарий "вам к фрилансерам", "это не фриланс-биржа" рассматриваются как агрессивные? Вопрос может содержать что-то вроде "с меня деньги на пиво", "в долгу не останусь". А даже если и нет, то почему опытный участник должен унижаться и писать сентенции вида "уважаемый username, не соблаговолите ли Вы рассмотреть редактирование своего безусловно полезного вопроса для приведения к привычному для сообщества вида (далее пара полезных ссылок) т.к. в текущем виде могут возникнуть подозрения, что возможно лучшим вариантом будет расширение диапазона поиска помощи до фриланс площадок" ?

Comment: @GreenDragon Не надо ничего писать! Такие вопросы вне тематики Stack Overflow. Их надо закрывать.

Comment: Выше я, конечно утрирую, но иногда самое лучшее решение проблемы - явно сказать об этом, а не делать намеки, которых многие могут просто не воспринять.

Comment: @GreenDragon Намеки тоже не нужны. Все что вне тематики и правил сайта надо закрывать. Например, как не содержащие вопроса.

Comment: Я согласен, но между "не надо писать" (в силу неэффективности или по каким-либо другим причинам) и "писать нельзя" есть большая разница.

Comment: @GreenDragon Почему бы тогда не остановиться на «не следует»? Запрета же никакого нет, и я предлагаю сообществу обращать на подобные комментарии самое пристальное внимание и как–только они выходят за рамки правил — удалять.

Comment: Сколько из 142 задавали свой вопрос до этого? (и, не знаю, есть или нет возможность посмотреть судьбу этих вопросов т.е. разделить на живые и закрытые/удаленные). Я не вижу связи между уходом участника и упоминанием фриланса. А если она есть, то может это и хорошо - SO помогло 142 людям найти направление куда копать - искать именно фриланс-биржу. Не надо бороться за число пользователей, надо улучшать контент.

Comment: @GreenDragon В основном, это был их первый и последний вопрос. Обратите внимание, что дружественная атмосфера и взаимное уважение — это не «борьба» за конкретных участников. Это основа основ построения сообщества.

Comment: Давайте уважать право участников рекомендовать обращаться на фриланс-биржы. Обратите внимание, что сделать это можно и без потери дружественной атмосферы и взаимного уважения. Если участник ведет себя как хам, то это обязательно проявится при комментировании, будет зафлагано(и, я надеюсь, к нему будут приняты меры со стороны администрации). А если нет, то не надо думать что он не может адекватно сформулировать предложение найти более подходящий ресурс.

Comment: Я в авто-чате об этом писал, но раз ссылка не видна, то повторю. Давайте разделять аргументацию к "нельзя" и "не актуально". Второе обоснованная причина для удаления старых фриланс-комментариев. Если вопрос доведен до ума, а не закрыт то будущим читателям фриланс уже без надобности, а если нет - сносить вопрос вместе с комментариями.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky "Только представьте, мы «отшили» 142 человека". Занятно, вы же вроде не глупый человек и должны понимать, что нет никакой прямой корреляции между комментарием о фрилансе и тем, что человек ушёл навсегда. Я склонен считать, что эти люди ушли, т.к. они пришли лишь за ответом, а сами контрибьютить и не собирались.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, **1.** В моём вопросе было `к участникам, **многократно** продолжающим`, в Вашем сообщении — `причины для репрессий за **один** такой комментарий (и даже за **два**!)`. «многократно» ≠ «1, 2». Просьба ответить на поставленый вопрос. // **2.** Вопрос — `Будут ли приниматься **административные меры**`; Ваш комментарий — `Я лично не вижу причины для **репрессий**`. Полагаю, термины `административная мера` и `репрессии` несут разный смысл. Так, предупреждение от модератора может относиться к `административным мерам`, но не `репрессиям`.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, остальное понятно. Спасибо.

Comment: Я просто уверен, что являюсь одним из этих 56 человек, кто оставил более пяти комментариев про фриланс. Прошу подтвердить, так ли это (я не скрываюсь). Также, не прошу раскрыть остальных имён (уважаю чужое право на приватность), но прошу просто оценить, какой вклад в модерирование сообщества внесли эти 56 человек. Вот вы пишете, что мы обидели аж 142 лентяя, которые и так бы свалили с сайта - а ничего, если мы постоянно прессуем самых активных участников сайта и демотивируем их выполнять работу по расчистке сайта?

Comment: И я тоже наверняка среди них.

Comment: Ну и меня в этот списочек внесите.

Comment: Всё пойдут под трибунал =D

Comment: @VladD На самом деле, если и есть, то в самых последних рядах. Пожалуйста, подскажите, можете ли вы сформулировать ответом (1) почему нам следует рассказывать человеку про фриланс/что этот сайт не фриланс; (2) задать правило, чтобы понимать в каких случаях допустимо подсказывать про фриланс; (3) примерный комментарий–причину закрытия вопроса, которую бы мы все смогли использовать для закрытия вопросов, попадающих под критерий 2.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, (1) Потому что... этот сайт - не фриланс? (2) В правилах об этом стоит написать, что, впрочем, [уже есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), но так ванильно, что никто не разберёт. (3) Причина подобная уже есть, только про учебные задания. Можно, конечно, сделать именно для фриланса, но это лишнее ИМХО.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Для ответа слишком коротко и не по теме. (1) Мы не должны устанавливать вовсе, какими словами стоит и не стоит пользоваться. (2) Правило не нужно, как мне кажется. Иногда комментарий о фрилансе уместен — например, там, где участник хочет получить готовое задание, но не хочет научиться программировать. Но поскольку это невозможно формализовать, то и не нужно пытаться. 3. Я редко употребляю такую формулировку, поэтому сформулировать изящно не могу. Я обычно пишу что-то вроде «Домашку нужно делать самостоятельно, стыдитесь».

Answer (score 5):

Я какое-то время думал, что это неплохая причина для закрытия вопроса. Вот почему:

Вопрос номер 1:
[Перевести код Pascal на Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/815985)

Автор не задает вопроса, это по сути заказ на перевод. Этот вопрос не гуглится, т.к. в нем нет вопроса и нет ошибки есть просто код.

---

Вопрос номер 2:
[Перевести код с Java AWT на JavaFX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768896/)

Чем это отличается от первого? Автор описал, что не получилось. Т.е. он почти все доделал сам, но возникли проблемы с которыми он пришел. Ему с радостью помогли. Так же он ещё и вознаграждение поставил, некоторым приятно получить не просто галочку а чуть больше кармы (своеобразная оплата).

---

Вопрос номер 3:
[Аналог scanf в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727457)

Автору не нужен перевод его кода или выполнение работы за него. Вопрос есть, есть ответ

---

Вопрос номер 4:
[C++ to Java - эквивалент функции swap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/394454)

Автор как и в 3 вопросе задал интересующий его вопрос и получил ответ.

---

Первый вопрос - чистый заказ, автор не сделал ничего, чтобы помочь себе. Он не преодолел себя что бы публично задать этот вопрос. Он просто скопипастил и написал, что ему нужно. В чуть более подробном виде размещают заказы на фриланс биржах.

Остальные это просьба помочь доделать, а не сделать за автора что-либо. Такие заказы не несут пользы никому. Даже если сравнить количество просмотров, из в 3-4 раза меньше у "заказов", если не больше.

Comment: Не очень понятно ваше отношение к вопросу со 2 по 4 и как они связаны с "фриланс"-комментариями

Comment: Во всех вопросах требуется помощь на пересечении 2 языков. 2-4  приведены как пример хороших и полезных вопросов. Первый - чистый фриланс, там не решение проблемы нужно, а просто перевод. Остальные задают вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы здесь не только про "фриланс" говорил, а про любой комментарий

1. обесценивающий усилия ТС по формулировке вопроса и определённую смелость, чтобы задать вопрос
2. грубые комментарии намекащие на отстуствие усилий а-ля "а погуглить не пробовали", высмеиващие некомпетентность автора и т.д.

Моя практика показала, что не все здесь понимают, что комментарии нужны либо для получения дополнительной информации, либо для очень деликатного направления ТС в нужное русло, чтобы ему помочь решить задачу и не почувствовать себя униженным.

Очень бы хотелось, чтобы у пользователей была терпимость к новичкам. Даже проголосовав против вопроса и/или за закрытие, если есть что сказать, то можно

- помочь автору понять правила,
- рассказать ему, как можно было бы улучшить свой вопрос или с чего ему можно начать, чтобы решить свою проблему и т.д.
- делитикатно ему рассказать о тех моментах, где он принял неудачные решения и как можно было бы лучше.

---

Я очень бы хотел, чтобы для всех это было банально и очевидно, и данное место не превращалось в площадку, где можно неэкологично "выпускать пар".

Comment: Joel Spolsky не давно явно об этом говорил в ["Strange and maddening rules"](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2018/04/23/strange-and-maddening-rules/) упоминая что "rudeness, snark, or condescension" являются проблемой и "the snark currently runs unchecked"

Comment: @jfs У меня 502 почему-то по ссылке.

Comment: это временная ошибка, ещё раз попробуйте. Может связано с тем, что wordpress с telegram ip диапазоны пересекаются (на aws?)

Answer (score 4):

"Фриланс" и "домашка" - две самые негативно воспринимаемые участниками темы на stackoverflow. И Николас [согласен](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7174/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-stack-overflow#comment28854_7175), что тут им не место:

> Не надо ничего писать! Такие вопросы вне тематики Stack Overflow. Их
>   надо закрывать

Вопросы у него вызывает то, что часто подобные комментарии ставятся там, где не надо - в спорных темах или вполне нормальных темах. Мол, это отпугивает нормальных людей.

И тут на мой взгляд Николас недоработал: не привёл ни одного примера в своей теме. Мне вспоминается [аналогичная тема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6189/213987) от PashaPash - он когда то же самое произошло с домашкой (закрывали нормальные вопросы с причиной "домашка") приводил конкретные примеры тем, собирал статистику. С моей точки зрения та тема была прекрасно подготовлена в отличие от текущей - и поэтому конструктивность обсуждения там была намного выше.

Разумеется, если мы ставим *на нормальные вопросы* язвительное клеймо "фриланс" и закрываем вопросы это плохо. Но нужны цифры, а цифр нет. Я вижу некоторые данные и графики (они появились к сожалению не ДО дискуссии, а в процессе), но к ним у меня возникают вопросы:

- Ну окей, число комментариев стало явно больше за последние годы в абсолютном отношении - но ведь и вопросов стали задавать больше. Можно посчитать удельную долю комментариев (к числу заданных вопросов) - это будет прям эпидемия-эпидемия (доля комментариев составляет 90% и растёт от года к году) или это почти всегда 0,05% и не растёт?
- Нам дана некая оценка, что комментарии оставляют одни и те же люди, их буквально 50 человек. К чему эти цифры? Вывод какой? Не делается. Попробую сделать сам гипотетическое утверждение. Если взять самое ядро аудитории сайта, которое постоянно пишет ответы и помогает модерировать - то обнаружится значительное пересечение и корреляция. Интересно, вот никто наверное не боится, что эти люди будут возмущены, что им будут тыкать в нос "что ж вы такие-сякие нехорошие слова пишете, аудиторию сайта отпугиваете"? Или просто тихо перестанут модерировать? Или начнут возмущаться и ставить минусы в этой теме, не осознавая своё возмущение? Ключевой вопрос в России - это уважение, нет ли тут неуважения к этой категории и почему об этом не говорится? На одной чаше - 50 человек, постоянно создающих добавочную ценность сайта - на другой 803 комментария с неизвестной оценкой, сколько было неправедно оскорблённых вопроса.

Когда появятся цифры и масштабы бедствия (сейчас звучат экспертные оценки "масштаб проблемы преувеличен") - тогда и можно будет предметно говорить. Когда PashaPash подымал вопрос - это было действительно масштабно, сейчас же проблема высосана из пальца, уж извините за прямоту: триста вопросов за полтора года - это один вопрос в сутки. (Напомнить, сколько [вопросов в день](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) на сайте задаётся? Двести в сутки!) Из этих триста вопросов наберётся хотя бы сто неправедно закрытых?

Итого: тему закрыть и начать заново, когда будут цифры. Имху, есть более важные вопросы, чем этот.

Comment: Подскажите, если вы видите что–то, его вроде бы быть не должно, но оно происходит, как вы пишите, раз в сутки. Будете ли вы ждать пока будет происходить 300 раз в сутки и остановить будет сложнее или все–таки своевременно отреагируете? Мне кажется куда более эффективным второй вариант. Если вы хотите увидеть большие цифр или какие–то конкретные, пожалуйста, напишите явно, какие именно.

Comment: Также, предположу, что чтобы найти решение следует убрать личностную характеристику. Если вы хотите «поставить жирный» минус, пожалуйста! Но это не обоснование почему фриланс–комментарии должны быть на сайте, почему они допустимы и как они влияют на сообщество. Сейчас я вижу в вашем ответе вашу личную оценку одного участника, но не причину и цель данных комментариев. Если вы считаете, что приведенных в ответе примеров не достаточно, приведите контр примеры или запросите еще.

Comment: Если вы считаете, что в какие–то случаях такие комментарии допустимы или нужны, пожалуйста, опишите в каких? В какой форме? Уровень конструктивности обсуждения задают авторы ответов, а не вопроса. Если вы сможете аргументировано показать, когда от использования подобных комментариев выиграет сообщество и/или автор вопроса, возможно мы сможем подобрать какие–то правила и сформулируем такую причину, которая пойдет на пользу всем.

Comment: Поднятие данной проблемы здесь на Мете, а не удаление молча, это, на мой взгляд, признак уважения. Большинство подобных комментариев все еще на сайте, ожидает момента, когда сообщество выскажет все за и против для детального рассмотрения проблемы.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky признак уважение это если после обсуждения на мете (судя по текущим голосам на ответах) , комментарии не будут удалены молча. Само по себе поднятие проблемы ни о чем не говорит, так как возможен и такой исход - "мы обсудили и я решил по-своему".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Считаю, что решать нужно сначала крупные проблемы, потом более мелкие. Из [обсуждения](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44254169#44254169) я вижу, что проблема точечная, про пару человек. Своё отношение к подобным комментариям я выразил: если мы ставим на нормальные вопросы язвительное клеймо "фриланс" и закрываем вопросы это плохо. Жаль, что вы услышали только критику в свой адрес: основная часть моего поста - в разъяснении о чём ваша тема. Да, я считаю, что вы объяснили плохо и подготовились плохо - поэтому расписал более подробно, что вы имели ввиду.